# Install JDK and set the path on linux 2.6.33-r2

Tags: linux, java

I have downloaded jdk7 from      "http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html"
and was trying to install it on linux platform (my OS is linux 2.6.33-gentoo-r2) by the given instructions in the website(mentioned above). 
In the given instructions, they mentioned that 
  "  Unpack the tarball and install the JDK.
    % tar zxvf jdk-7u-linux-x64.tar.gz     "
This was executed successfully. After that step i need to do ./configure.
But I'm not able to do that. It says command not found. I have tried with many sources, but couldn't get it. Could some one please help me?

Thanks in advance,
Arun

Comment: There is no `./configure', I'm not quite sure what instructions you're reading, but they certainly aren't the ones provided. You untar it, and you're done.

Comment: you don't need to configure jdk, just use it.

Comment: my question is how to set the path? I have tried the following : which java
which: no java in (/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/opt/bin:/usr/sparc-unknown-linux-gnu/gcc-bin/4.3.4:/usr/sparc-unknown-linux-gnu/sparc64-unknown-linux-gnu/gcc-bin/4.3.3:/usr/lib/jvm/java/bin)     ....... i got a jdk1.7.0 folder in etc after untar

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install JDK on Ubuntu (Linux)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14788345/how-to-install-jdk-on-ubuntu-linux)

Answer (score 2):

How to install "Open Jdk" (java developement kit) in Ubuntu(Linux)?

Step 1: Open Applicaction>> Accessories>> Terminal

Step 2: Type commandline as below...

```
      sudo apt-get install openjdk-6-jdk
```

Step 3: Type commandline as below...

```
      apt-cache search jdk
```

(Note: openjdk-6-jdk is symbolically used here you can choose jdk version as per your requirment.)

How to set "Environment Variables" for "Open jdk" in Ubuntu(Linux)?

Step 4: For "JAVA_HOME" (Environment Variable) type command as shown below, in "Terminal" using your installation path...

```
      export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk
```

(Note: "/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk" is symbolically used here just for demostration you should use your path as per your installation.)

Step 5: For "PATH" (Environment Variable) type command as shown below, in "Terminal" using your installation path...

```
      export PATH=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/bin
```

(Note: "/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk" is symbolically used here just for demostration you should use your path as per your installation.)

Step 6: Check for "open jdk" installation, just type command in "Terminal" as shown below
          javac

ths are steps for installation of jdk on ubuntu..... try for linux like this

Comment: Answer seems to be copied without attribution from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14788345/how-to-install-jdk-on-ubuntu-linux