# How to install the JDK on Ubuntu Linux

Tags: java, ubuntu

Note:  This is an old question and the answers reflect the world as it was then.  Modern Ubuntu distributions have OpenJDK available which can be installed with

```
sudo apt install default-jdk
```

---

I am trying to install the [Java Development Kit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Development_Kit) (JDK) on [Ubuntu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_%28operating_system%29) Linux distribution, but I am unable to install it.

What are the steps to install it on Ubuntu?

Comment: Which JDK version? Java6 or 7? 32 or 64 bit version?

Comment: [How can I install Sun/Oracle's proprietary Java 6/7 JRE or JDK?](http://askubuntu.com/q/56104/62483)

Comment: https://github.com/shahriyar1369/JDK_Source_installer_for_ubuntu

Answer (score 852, accepted):

Referring to *[Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/tour)* question *[How to set JAVA_HOME for OpenJDK?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/175514/how-to-set-java-home-for-openjdk)*,

How to install `Open JDK` (Java developement kit) in Ubuntu (Linux)?

1. Open *Terminal* from Application Dash or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
2. Update repository:

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:openjdk-r/ppa  # only Ubuntu 17.4 and earlier
   sudo apt update
   ```
3. Optional: To search available distributions of `openjdk`, use the following command:

   ```
   apt search openjdk
   ```
4. Install the appropriate version with the following command:

   ```
   sudo apt install openjdk-8-jdk
   sudo apt install openjdk-8-source #this is optional, the jdk source code
   ```
5. For `JAVA_HOME` (Environment Variable) type command as shown below, in "Terminal" using your installation path...

   ```
   export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk
   ```

   (Note: `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk` is symbolically used here just for demostration. You should use your path as per your installation.)
6. For `PATH` (Environment Variable) type command as shown below, in `Terminal`:

   `export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin`
7. To check your installation:

   `java -version`

Comment: I copied your "export PATH=" ... command and screwed up my box. Please correct it to: "export PATH=$PATH:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/bin"

Comment: I'd replace `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/bin` with `export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin`, which is more DRY

Comment: just replace everywhere java-6-openjdk  to java-7-openjdk if you want to install java7

Comment: Even after doing Nico's suggestions, my PATH variable was still all  screwed, still unable to use basic terminal commands.  The fix was to run:  export PATH=/usr/bin:/bin at the command prompt.  Then all was fine.

Comment: You better check what is the actual folder. In my case it was: `/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64`

Comment: To have it eternally : echo "export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk" >> ~/.bashrc           and            echo "export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin" >> ~/.bashrc

Comment: Now, it says Package openjdk-7-jdk is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

Comment: Just make sure that when using the JDK  you put the correct version number. In this case it is useful to go to the oracle page and just get the latest number which in my case was 8.

Comment: For ubuntu 16.04 use `openjdk-8-jdk` There is no`openjdk-7-jdk` see [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/759451/how-can-i-install-openjdk-on-ubuntu-16-04)

Comment: For Java version 8: `sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk`

Comment: In case someone want to install it to use JavaFx Oracle version is better, please see: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28126217/openjdk-does-not-work-with-javafx

Comment: This used to work, but now the first step
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:openjdk-r/ppa
no longer works.  Is there a work around to the repo not working?

Comment: `javac -version` does not shows verion, `java -version` shows the installed version

Comment: 'java -version' gives the version of the JRE, not the JDK. 'java' is used to execute java bytecode, while 'javac' is used to compile java programs into bytecode.  This answer is not correct.

Comment: To fix Not Found problems, use the following option(after install command): --fix-missing

Comment: How do you run the JDK at this point? is there an executable, or a terminal command?

Answer (score 208):

The following used to work before the Oracle Java license changes in early 2019.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer
```

The [PPA](https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/java) is discontinued, until the author finds a workaround for the license issues.

Comment: For more information: http://www.webupd8.org/2012/01/install-oracle-java-jdk-7-in-ubuntu-via.html

Comment: This is what I used.
If you want java6  :  
    sudo apt-get install oracle-java6-installer
.
if you want java8  :  
    sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
.

If you have multiple java installed on your system, you can select with  :  

    sudo update-alternatives --config java

Comment: This is the easiest answer and working with all jdk versions, just replace java7 with java6, 8 or 9 and you will be able to install the version you want!

Comment: Easy to remove them also, eg: sudo apt-get remove oracle-java7-installer

Comment: Is there a work around for the first step?  The ppa no longer works.

Comment: sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package oracle-java7-installer is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'oracle-java7-installer' has no installation candidate

Comment: As of March 2019 the ppa was disabled and now 99% of the answer regarding this issue around the internet cannot be used anymore.

Answer (score 151):

You can install Oracle's JDK 1.7 fairly easily too; as an example this is how to install JDK 1.7.0_13;

- Download the JDK [from Oracle's site](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html). The download to the newest version is always linked from http://java.oracle.com.

As root, do;

```
cd /usr/local
tar xzf <the file you just downloaded>
```

As your normal user, add or change these two lines in your ~/.profile to point to the installation;

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/jdk1.7.0_13
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```

If it's an update, you may also want to remove the old java installation directory in `/usr/local`.

Log out and in again (or do `. ~/.profile`), and everything should just work.

The downside with Oracle's JDK is that it won't update with the rest of your system like OpenJDK will, so I'd mostly consider it if you're running programs that require it.

Comment: do i need to give the path to the downloaded folder in tar xzf command

Comment: @Subash you need the downloaded file to be in th /usr/local directory before running the tar xzf command. To get that, cd to the path where your downloaded file is and run: `sudo mv <nameOfYourFile.tar.gz> /usr/local`

Comment: Hi, new to linux, I just have to extract the archive and it's installed?

Comment: You may also need to define aliases for JVM and Java Compiler and put them inside your `~/.profile` file:

`alias java='$JAVA_HOME/bin/java'` and 
`alias javac='$JAVA_HOME/bin/javac'`

Comment: just download the .rpm and use `alien` to install it. `sudo alien -i jdk-xxxxx.rpm`

Answer (score 79):

In case you have already downloaded the ZIP file follow these steps.

Run the following command to unzip your file.

```
tar -xvf ~/Downloads/jdk-7u3-linux-i586.tar.gz
sudo mkdir -p /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0
sudo mv jdk1.7.0_03/* /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0/
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0/bin/java" 1
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javac" "javac" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0/bin/javac" 1
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javaws" "javaws" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0/bin/javaws" 1
```

After installation is complete, set environment variables as follows.

Edit the system path in file `/etc/profile`:

```
sudo gedit /etc/profile
```

Add the following lines at the end.

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:$JAVA_HOME/bin
export JAVA_HOME
export PATH
```

Source: http://javaandme.com/

Comment: Thanks! I was looking for the method using update-alternatives

Comment: Where did the JRE_HOME variable come from?

Answer (score 62):

> **Note:** WebUpd8 team's PPA has been discontinued with effective from April 16, 2019. Thus this PPA doesn't have any Java files. More information can be found on [PPA's page on Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/%7Ewebupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/java). Hence the below method no longer works and exists because of historical reasons.

If you want to install the latest JDK 1.8, use the webupd8team PPA.

Add the repository in your system:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
```

You can now install Oracle Java 8 using the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

This ppa repository also provides a package to set environment variables automatically. Just type:

```
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-set-default
```

Answer (score 35):

OpenJDK is OK for the most cases, but Oracle JDK can be required for some bank client applications (my case) - I can't use OpenJDK.

I'm surprised that I don't see any answer with the default method (repository without external PPAs) in **Ubuntu 12.10+** for Oracle's JDK - I will try to describe it.

- Install [JavaPackage](https://wiki.debian.org/JavaPackage):
  `sudo apt-get install java-package`
- Download Oracle JDK from [Oracle downloads page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html)
- Make a Debian package from the downloaded `.tar.gz` archive:
  `make-jpkg jdk-YOUR_VERSION-linux-PLATFORM.tar.gz`
  This command will produce a `.deb` package.
- Install the package in your favourite way (for example, `sudo dpkg -i oracle-java8-jdk_8u40_amd64.deb`)

It's the officially supported way from Debian developers for installing Oracle JDK, and I suppose it's very simple.

Comment: This is easily the best answer. Took a couple minutes and gave the official JDK, since some apps don't like OpenJDK too much.

Comment: can we add the documentation with that method?

Comment: note: you can also install the documentation easily this way. this should be the most recommended way of installing java.

Answer (score 29):

> **Note:** WebUpd8 team's PPA has been discontinued with effective from April 16, 2019. Thus this PPA doesn't have any Java files. More information can be found on [PPA's page on Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/%7Ewebupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/java). Hence the below method no longer works and exists because of historical reasons.

**Installing Java 8 on Ubuntu**

First you need to add webupd8team Java PPA repository in your system and install Oracle Java 8 using following set of commands.

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

**Verify Installed Java Version**

After successfully installing Oracle Java using the above steps, verify the installed version using the following command.

```
$ java -version

java version "1.8.0_77"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_77-b03)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.77-b03, mixed mode)
```

###Configuring the Java environment

In Webupd8 ppa repository also providing a package to set environment variables, Install this package using following command.

```
$ sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-set-default
```

[Reference](http://tecadmin.net/install-oracle-java-8-jdk-8-ubuntu-via-ppa/)

Comment: Roughly the same thing worked for Java9:  `sudo apt-get install oracle-java9-installer`

Answer (score 24):

Simply run:

```
sudo apt-get install default-jdk
```

Comment: This is for Ubuntu 18.04+ only, I think.

Answer (score 8):

[Wiki from Ubuntu website:](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LucidLynx/ReleaseNotes#Sun%20Java%20moved%20to%20the%20Partner%20repository)

For **Ubuntu 10.04 LTS**, the sun-java6 packages have been dropped from the Multiverse section of the Ubuntu archive. It is recommended that you use openjdk-6 instead.

*If you can not switch from the proprietary Sun JDK/JRE to OpenJDK, you can install sun-java6 packages from the Canonical Partner Repository. You can configure your system to use this repository via command-line:*

```
 sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ lucid partner"
 sudo apt-get update   
 sudo apt-get install sun-java6-jre sun-java6-plugin
 sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

For **Ubuntu 10.10**, the sun-java6 packages have been dropped from the Multiverse section of the Ubuntu archive. It is recommended that you use openjdk-6 instead.

*If you can not switch from the proprietary Sun JDK/JRE to OpenJDK, you can install sun-java6 packages from the Canonical Partner Repository. You can configure your system to use this repository via command-line:*

```
 sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ maverick partner"
 sudo apt-get update   
 sudo apt-get install sun-java6-jre sun-java6-plugin
 sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

Answer (score 8):

**Installed in ubuntu 18.04**

My workaround was,

```
$ sudo apt update
```

Install OpenJDK 8:

```
$ sudo apt install openjdk-8-jdk
```

Verify the Java installation by running the following command which will print the Java version:

```
$ java -version
```

The output should look like this:

Output:

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_191"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_191-8u191-b12-2ubuntu0.18.04.1-b12)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.191-b12, mixed mode)
```

Answer (score 7):

#### Using a PPA (Obsolete)

> **Note:** WebUpd8 team's PPA has been discontinued with effective from April 16, 2019. Thus this PPA doesn't have any Java files. More information can be found on [PPA's page on Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/%7Ewebupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/java). Hence the below method no longer works and exists because of historical reasons.

You can use [WebUpd8 PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Ewebupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/java) (this will download the required files from Oracle and install JDK 8):

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

[Are PPA's safe to add to my system and what are some “red flags” to watch out for?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35629/are-ppas-safe-to-add-to-my-system-and-what-are-some-red-flags-to-watch-out-fo)

Also ensure your JAVA_HOME variable has been set to:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
```

#### Manual install

The tar.gz provided by Oracle don't have an actual installation process. You just extract those files to a location you want and add them to your path. So the process is the following:

Download a `.tar.gz` from [Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html) (here I will be using jdk-8u20-linux-x64.tar.gz);
Extract it to somewhere;

Move the extracted folder to `/usr/lib/jvm`. This is not required but it is the place where Java runtime software is installed

```
sudo mv /path/to/jdk1.8.0_20 /usr/lib/jvm/oracle_jdk8
```

Create a file `/etc/profile.d/oraclejdk.sh` with the following content (adapt the paths to reflect the path where you stored your JDK):

```
export J2SDKDIR=/usr/lib/jvm/oracle_jdk8
export J2REDIR=/usr/lib/jvm/oracle_jdk8/jre
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/lib/jvm/oracle_jdk8/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/oracle_jdk8/db/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/oracle_jdk8/jre/bin
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/oracle_jdk8
export DERBY_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/oracle_jdk8/db
```

Done! Those paths will only be recognized after you logout or restart, so if you want to use them right away run `source /etc/profile.d/oraclejdk.sh`.

Answer (score 6):

In **Ubuntu 18.04**, We can install java like a normal package without using an external repository

Just run this command

```
sudo apt install openjdk-8-jdk
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `sudo apt-get install default-jdk` terminal command to install the *default JDK* version.

Before installing Java, type the `sudo apt-get update` terminal command and then type the `install terminal` command. You can get more information from [here](https://progtpoint.blogspot.com/2017/01/tutorial-12-install-java-in-ubuntu.html).

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at [OpenJDK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenJDK). It is the standard [JVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine) implementation on Linux.

Answer (score 4):

I recommend [JavaPackage](https://wiki.debian.org/JavaPackage).

It's very simple. You just need to follow the instructions to create a .deb package from the Oracle tar.gz file.

Answer (score 4):

You can install via `apt-get`:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linuxuprising/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java11-installer
```

After, do not forget to check the version:

```
java -version
```

Answer (score 4):

The best is to install default Java until a specific Java version is not required. 
Before this, execute *java -version* to check if Java is not already installed.

```
sudo apt-get update  
sudo apt-get install default-jre  
sudo apt-get install default-jdk
```

That is everything that is needed to install **Java**.

Comment: sudo apt install default-jre       
sudo apt install openjdk-11-jre-headless
sudo apt install openjdk-8-jre-headless

Answer (score 4):

You can use [SDKMan](https://sdkman.io),

```
curl -s "https://get.sdkman.io" | bash
source "~/.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh"
sdk install java
```

Answer (score 3):

sun-java6-jdk is a virtual package provided by oracle-java8-installer or oracle-java7-installer or oracle-java7-installer.

```
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

will give you sun-java6-jdk.

Comment: `oracle-java8-installer` is available only from external PPA

Answer (score 3):

I have successfully installed JDK 10 on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS following [this video](https://youtu.be/4RJ60fqeTN4).

I am copying the excerpt from the description of the video.

Just open the terminal and give these commands :

For Java Installation (PPA)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linuxuprising/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java10-installer
```

For setting up environment variables (make java10 default)

```
sudo apt-get install oracle-java10-set-default
```

The same procedure can be followed on  Ubuntu 16.04, Linux Mint, Debian and other related Linux systems to install JDK 10.

Answer (score 3):

Try to use SDKMAN! package manager - https://sdkman.io/install
Now it's the easiest way to install many JVM-based SDKs, tools and frameworks on any Linux distribution.

Upon installation, run the following command to see all available Java distributions:

```sh
sdk list java
```

Select the distribution that you need and install it:

```sh
sdk install java <version>
```

Comment: This actually has the added bonus of managing multiple `Java` versions. So if you have multiple projects that require different versions, you can easily switch.

Answer (score 3):

1. Install the appropriate version of OpenJDK

   `JAVA_VERSION=8
   sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:openjdk-r/ppa
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get -qq install -y openjdk-$JAVA_VERSION-jdk`
2. Set Environment Variables in /etc/profile.d/jdk.sh

   `JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-$JAVA_VERSION-openjdk-amd64
   echo "export JAVA_HOME=$JAVA_HOME" | sudo tee -a /etc/profile.d/jdk.sh
   echo "export J2SDKDIR=$JAVA_HOME" | sudo tee -a /etc/profile.d/jdk.sh
   echo "export J2REDIR=$JAVA_HOME/jre" | sudo tee -a /etc/profile.d/jdk.sh
   echo "export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin:$J2REDIR/bin" | sudo tee -a /etc/profile.d/jdk.sh`
3. Check your installation

   `/bin/bash /etc/profile.d/jdk.sh
   java -version
   echo $JAVA_HOME
   echo $J2REDIR
   echo $PATH`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to install Oracle JDK, you can [use this automated script](https://github.com/AdamScheller/UbuntuJavaInstaller) that does all the work for you.

There are detailed instructions how to use it [on the author's blog](http://adamscheller.com/linux/how-to-install-java-on-ubuntu/).

Answer (score 2):

Installing Oracle's Java JDK requires you to accept the Oracle license before the installation begins. This is only required once. If for some reason you need the installation to be automated, you can run the following commands to install without user interaction, useful for an automatic script for example.

```
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
echo debconf shared/accepted-oracle-license-v1-1 select true | sudo debconf-set-selections
echo debconf shared/accepted-oracle-license-v1-1 seen true | sudo debconf-set-selections
sudo apt-get -y install oracle-java8-installer
java -version
```

Answer (score 2):

**Step 01:** **Download JDK**

Download the JDK of required version from oracle official website :
[Oracle website to download JDK]: https://www.oracle.com/in/java/technologies/javase-downloads.html

```
 e.i - jdk-11.0.12_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz
```

**Step 02:** **Installation:**

a) Extract the downloaded files using following command

```
sudo -tar -vzxf jdk-11.0.12_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz
```

b) Create a directory of name **java** inside **usr/lib** directory

```
mkdir java
```

c) Move the extracted **jdk-11.0.12** directory inside the new created directory **java**

```
sudo mv jdk-11.0.12 /usr/lib/java
```

**Step 03:**

a) Execute following commands one by one

```
sudo update-alternative -install /usr/lib/java java /usr/lib/java/jdk-11.0.12/bin/java 1

sudo update-alternative -install /usr/lib/javac javac /usr/lib/java/jdk-11.0.12/bin/javac 1
```

**Step 04: installation varification :**

Verify the installation by using following commands

```
 java --version
 javac --version
```

Comment: `update-alternative` command not found

Comment: sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /usr/lib/jdk/jdk-11.0.12/bin/java 1

Comment: Your update-alteratives commands have several issues, including that it breaks the `/usr/bin/java` link when I execute it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [oraji](https://github.com/neurobin/oraji). It can install/uninstall both JDK or JRE from oracle java (.tar.gz).

1. To install run `sudo oraji '/path/to/the/jdk_or_jre_archive'`
2. To uninstall run `oraji -u` and confirm the version number.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and none of the comments worked for me. Finally, I noticed that I disabled my updates. When I reactivate it, so  sudo apt-get update worked correctly and the issue was solved.
(update in system settings> software and updates>updates tab 
here I ticked two first option of important update and recommended updates).

Answer (score 1):

Try this in case you do not want to install OpenJDK: *[JDK Source Installer for Ubuntu](https://github.com/shahriyar1369/JDK_Source_installer_for_ubuntu)*

Answer (score 0):

In **Ubuntu1604** I faced "No installation candidate error". Following below steps helped me install.

-sudo apt-get update
-sudo apt-get upgrade
-apt-get install software-properties-common
-sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
-apt-get update
-sudo apt install oracle-java8-installer

Answer (score 0):

Over Debian you can try

```
apt-get install default-jdk
```

Answer (score 0):

I just did this on an Ubuntu virtual machine.  Here's how I did it.

Ubuntu comes with the Java JRE installed, but not the JDK.  Java -version gives the JRE, not the JDK.  Run javac -version.  If the JDK isn't installed, you will get an error. Run the following command in the terminal to get the JDK: `sudo apt install default-jdk`.  Now, run `which javac`.  The output should be `/usr/bin/javac`. It has now been installed.  IntelliJ won't let us use this path because it is the binary of javac. Go to Project Structure > Project Settings > Project.  Where it says 'Project SDK', add a JDK.  Then go to /usr/lib/jvm.  Now you should be able to compile java projects in IntellIJ.

You may have to edit the configurations so that IntelliJ knows where to look for your main class.  Go to Run > Edit Configurations.  Add your main class for the Main class and add the root of your project as the Working directory.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow this step to install oracle JDK

1. Download oracle JDK (Eg Java 8 for 64 bit machine **jdk-8u241-linux-x64.tar.gz** ) from [Oracle](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html)
2. Extract the *.tar.gz in home directory or preferred location
3. Set Environment variable 
   Eg Open terminal type **sudo gedit ~/.bashrc** 
     Add following line at end of .bashrc file

   **export JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk1.8.0_241**  #add your own jdk location

   **export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin**
4. Save and exit
5. Finally source the .bashrc
   Eg **source ~/.bashrc**
6. Now open a new terminal type **jdk -version**

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to use the AdoptOpenJDK distribution other than Java 10, you can use their official repository as described on the [AdoptOpenJDK website](https://adoptopenjdk.net/installation.html#linux-pkg) (also applies for Debian):

> 1. Import the official AdoptOpenJDK GPG key by running the following command:
>
>    ```
>    wget -qO - https://adoptopenjdk.jfrog.io/adoptopenjdk/api/gpg/key/public | sudo apt-key add -
>    ```
> 2. Import the AdoptOpenJDK DEB repository by running the following command:
>
>    ```
>    sudo add-apt-repository --yes https://adoptopenjdk.jfrog.io/adoptopenjdk/deb/
>    ```
>
>    If you get a command not found error, try running:
>
>    ```
>    apt-get install -y software-properties-common
>    ```
>
>    Then repeat the first command.
> 3. Refresh your package list with apt-get update and then install your chosen AdoptOpenJDK package. For example, to install OpenJDK 8 with the HotSpot VM, run:
>
>    ```
>    apt-get install <adoptopenjdk-8-hotspot>
>    ```

You can find the available packange names / Java versions under https://adoptopenjdk.jfrog.io/adoptopenjdk/deb/pool/main/a/

Answer (score -3):

Execute these series of commands (insert, update, and install) and you are all set to go.

1. First add the repository:

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
   ```
2. Update:

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   ```
3. Install:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer
   ```