# How do I tell Gradle to use specific JDK version?

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle

I can't figure out to get this working.

Scenario:

- I have an application built with gradle
- The application uses JavaFX

What I want

- Use a variable (defined per developer machine) which points to an installation of a JDK which will be used for building the whole application / tests / ...

I thought about having the `gradle.properties` file, defining the variable. Something like

```
JAVA_HOME_FOR_MY_PROJECT=<path to my desired JDK>
```

What I don't want

- point `JAVA_HOME` to the desired JDK

I could live with many suggestions:

- a solution that defines a system environment variable which I'm able to check in my build.gradle script
- a variable defined in gradle.properties
- overriding the JAVA_HOME variable only for the build context (something like `use JAVA_HOME=<my special JDK path defined somewhere else defined>`)
- something else I didn't think about

Question:

- How to wire a variable (how ever defined, as variable in the `gradle.properties`, system environment variable, ...) to the build process?

I have more than one JDK7 available and need to point to a special version (minimum JDK_u version).

Any answer is appreciated and I'm thankful for every hint to the right direction.

Comment: Have you tried setting `org.gradle.java.home` in the `gradle.properties` file? [link](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/build_environment.html)

Comment: in eclipse you can create "product config file" in to your project and you can pack the jdk with your product. No need to specify env variables.

Comment: @RayStojonic: I just gave it a try, but gradle still uses the JAVA_HOME JDK for building :(

Comment: @mdanaci: I was really hoping I could avoid this because I honestly don't want to take a JDK under version control (which would be the consequence if I would use your suggestion) as any developer has to be able to pack the application. Plus, I see problems with the CI server this way. Thanks for your suggestion anyway :)

Comment: As of a year ago, the `org.gradle.java.home` setting applies only to gradle daemon, apparently... At any rate, try setting fork to true and forkOptions.executable to the jdk you want to use: [link](http://forums.gradle.org/gradle/topics/setting_path_to_jdk)

Comment: ah, too bad, I missed the link (though I found it on Google, but now I have a different sense for the content). Thanks, that did the trick, great :)

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22681544/how-to-set-gradle-options-bootclasspath-in-an-os-independent-manner - it is essentially the same question and it provides a way to run the gradle using one jdk and compile the project (or any module) using the other jdk.

Comment: To instead set the *source* and *target* SDK versions, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/19470405/712526.

Answer (score 482, accepted):

Two ways

1. In `gradle.properties` in the `.gradle` directory in your `HOME_DIRECTORY` set `org.gradle.java.home=/path_to_jdk_directory`

or:

2. In your `build.gradle`

   ```
    compileJava.options.fork = true
    compileJava.options.forkOptions.executable = '/path_to_javac'
   ```

Comment: The `gradle.properties` can be defined at project level too, see http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/build_environment.html

Comment: If you are executing using gradle wrapper you can also do it like  `./gradlew -Dorg.gradle.java.home=/path_to_jdk_directory`. Good if you don't want to touch `gradle.properties`.

Comment: The question was how to set VERSION, not JDK PATH, wasn't it?

Comment: @Dims thats exactly how you do it, you have different versions of Java in different paths, then whichever version you want to use give that path. javac is a compiler(The program that actually compiles java code to byte code in the JDK), and its not hosted in Maven or Ivy repositories like how dependency libs are.

Comment: This way I can't share project with other developers, who have java in different paths.

Comment: How do I set the version much like in ant where if developers JAVA_HOME is 1.6, the build fails telling them version must be 1.8 and to change their JAVA_HOME.  I don't want other developers be required to have the same JAVA_HOME path as me(or make them even be on the same OS)?

Comment: @Dims you can place in gradle.properties the path to java home, but it can be through a variable defined in a gradle-wraper.properties for example, this way you can export your project

Comment: There's a difference between options 1 and 2 that should be clarified: In option 1 we are setting the JVM for gradle itself to run under which will also be used to run the compiler task (notice that javac itself is a java application), while in option 2 we are just setting javac to be spawned in its own JVM. If for whatever reason we need a specific JVM for gradle (e.g a given gradle plugin is compiled for say Java 8), then we would be forced to resort to forking a separate JVM for the compile process.

Comment: This is an interesting fix, but it could get interesting if you support building on more than one platform, and you also have different subprojects requiring different versions. It's a shame it can't be more declarative - you say which version you require, and per-system configuration takes care of saying where those actually are. Actually, it's a shame it can't just pull an artifact containing the JDK from the artifact server, so that when we bump the version of the JDK we depend on, people don't all have to go and manually download that version.

Comment: If you are using the gradle **wrapper**, you can use way 1 of @FirstZero : in your home path `\.gradle`, create  a `gradle.properties` file, and add the line `org.gradle.java.home=/path_to_jdk_directory`.

Comment: Note that properties files use backslash escaping, so for a Windows-style path you'll need double backslashes.

Comment: in my case strange behaviour each time i rechange to JDK8 and try build it changes back to 7 , the solution was default JDK for IDE find here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18987228/how-do-i-change-the-intellij-idea-default-jdk

Comment: just for anyone uses Mac OS and needs to know where it `path_to_jdk_directory`. In my case is will be found in `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/` folder. Example: `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_172.jdk`.

Comment: If I use option 1 does it mean that if I run afterwards 'gradle -v' it would show me the previously set java version? I didn't observe it. It seems that gradle still uses the java set in JAVA_HOME and not in gradle.properties. Do I have to do some restart or refresh? I'm using linux.

Comment: I didn't had `gradle.properties` in my `~/.gradle` but I added one it is working fine.

Comment: @Nezneika I'm also on a Mac and in my case I had to write `org.gradle.java.home=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_172.jdk/Contents/Home`

Comment: Point 1 was how we got sorted, thank you so much! We upgraded our app to use Gradle 7 and part of that is running Java 11. For some reason despite our JAVA_HOME and -javac returning jdk11, this is how we got our builds to work!

Comment: I don't see any jdk version or path in "build.gradle". My ".gradle" directory doesn't have any "gradle.properties". I'm using IntelliJ.

Answer (score 280):

If you add JDK_PATH in **gradle.properties** your build become dependent on on that particular path.
Instead Run **gradle task** with following command line parametemer

```
gradle build -Dorg.gradle.java.home=/JDK_PATH
```

This way your build is not dependent on some concrete path.

Comment: In Eclipse (Neon, 4.6) you can also set the Java Home within the Gradle build configuration (see tab "Java Home"). This is somewhat tedious work if you have 20+ build jobs...
I think Gradle really needs to pick the Java Home directory from the system's configuration!

Comment: This is a fair point.  I have a soft-link called `/usr/lib/java/jdk/home` that points to the _current_ version installed.  Of course when you want a specific version (e.g. u51) then you need to be specific about the path.  Also some tools want to kick-off gradle don't seem to set the JDK in the environment they give gradle.  And I for one never set the JDK as the current JAVA_HOME unless it is a development session.

Comment: Note that JDK_PATH can't have spaces on Windows, even if it's in quotes: you have change "Program Files" to `PROGRA~1` (all caps) or whatever else DIR /X tells you.

Comment: Not working for me. However, I'm using gradlew war (wrapper), maybe this is the cause?

Comment: If you are using gradle wrapper invoke the command like this

./gradlew build -Dorg.gradle.java.home=/JDK_PATH

Replace JDK_PATH with your jdk location in your environment 
like ' /opt/java/jdk1.7.0_79/bin/'

Comment: @mirmdasif That's what I'm doing. However, since the default on the machine is Java6, it seems to want to use that instead of the path I specified. I'll keep on looking for solutions using this approach.

Comment: `"... gradle itself (either standalone distribution or wrapper) uses JDK from JAVA_HOME environment variable or (if it is not set) from PATH".` I specified the JAVA_HOME prior to gradlew call to fix this. (ie. `env JAVA_HOME=/path/to/java gradlew war --stacktrace`)

Comment: I've tried running this: ```.\gradlew.bat bootRun -Dorg.gradle.java.home="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60" --info```
But am getting this error: 
```Project '.gradle.java.home=C' not found in root project 'grails3-quick-start'.```

Comment: You need to put 2 backslashes for paths in windows so run this .\gradlew.bat bootRun -Dorg.gradle.java.home="C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_60"

Comment: On MacOS for Java 8: `-Dorg.gradle.java.home=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/`

Comment: Example for JDK 8 on MacOSX to add the path dynamically: ./gradlew clean build -Dorg.gradle.java.home=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8`

Comment: **WINDOWS** example: `.\gradlew test -D"org.gradle.java.home"="D:\jdk\jdk8oj9"` (mind the quotes)

Comment: thanks. in 2022 i need to write `org.gradle.java.home=/JDK_PATH` inside the gradle.properties, removing the `gradle build -D` prefix from the answer

Comment: My OS is Linux and I have my JAVA_HOME pointing to the correct path. I have even used this command `gradle build -Dorg.gradle.java.home=$JAVA_HOME` to prove my point. I've installed gradle using snap in Ubuntu and I'm guessing it is using some bundled JDK.

Comment: On macOS Sonoma (version 14.1), if you want to use `java_home` command and specify a concrete version of JDK, the following works  (example for JDK 17): `./gradlew -Dorg.gradle.java.home=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 17)`. I.e. unlike the above mentioned commands, where `java_home` was used without any enclosing constructions, I used the [***command substitution***](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Command-Substitution) (this `$(command)` construction), otherwise it didn't work.

Answer (score 202):

To people ending up here when searching for the Gradle equivalent of the Maven property `maven.compiler.source` (or `<source>1.8</source>`):

In build.gradle you can achieve this with

```
apply plugin: 'java'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8
```

See the [Gradle documentation on this](https://docs.gradle.org/3.3/userguide/java_plugin.html#sec:java_convention_properties).

### Gradle 7+

From Gradle 7 onwards, you can also use [the `release` property](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.CompileOptions.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.CompileOptions:release), which makes use of the JDK 9 [`--release` compiler argument](https://openjdk.org/jeps/247):

```
tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.release = 8
}
```

(thanks Pedro Lamarão)

Comment: @morgwai -- except that this *isn't* the answer to the question, which explicitly asks "What I want [is to set] a variable (defined per developer machine) which points to an installation of a JDK which will be used for building the whole application".  The upvoted answers are correct; this answer is for an entirely different question.

Comment: This is ignored by tools such as the Javadoc task (which tries to generate the javadoc according to Java 9 with modules on my project that is specified to use Java 8)

Comment: While not an exact answer for this question, this way actually works for more than just one system. Most people searching this question want to see this answer and not the other answers.

Comment: I asked Google for "gradle specify jdk version" and it brought me here. The answer I was actually looking for is this one, regardless of what the question was actually about. Upvoted because useful.

Comment: "except that this isn't the answer to the question", The question actually asks two questions... one is "specific JDK version?" (by title), the other is "an installation of a JDK" (by description).  In my experience, the former is often more useful as newer JDKs can often target older JDK versions, allowing the existing location to achieve what the title (perhaps accidentally) asks.

Comment: For those coming in the future, Gradle's `JavaCompile` task now allows setting the `release` option. https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.CompileOptions.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.CompileOptions:release

Comment: idea says it's better to do `tasks.withType(JavaCompile).configureEach`, instead of just `tasks.withType(JavaCompile)`

Answer (score 113):

## Gradle 6.7+ — Use Gradle Toolchain Support

The right way to do this with modern versions of Gradle (version 6.7+) is to use the [Gradle Java Toolchain](https://blog.gradle.org/java-toolchains) [support](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/toolchains.html).

The following block, when the java plugin is applied to the current project, will use Java 11 in all java compilation, test, and javadoc tasks:

```
java {
  toolchain {
    languageVersion.set(JavaLanguageVersion.of(11))
  }
}
```

This can also be set for [individual tasks](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/toolchains.html#specify_custom_toolchains_for_individual_tasks).

NOTE: For [other tasks relying on a Java executable or Java home](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/toolchains.html#integration_with_tasks_relying_on_a_java_executable_or_java_home), use the compiler metadata to set the appropriate options. See below for an example with the Kotlin plugin, prior to version 1.5.30.

Gradle attempts to [auto-detect](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/toolchains.html#sec:auto_detection) the location of the specified JDK via several common mechanisms. [Custom locations](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/toolchains.html#sec:custom_loc) can be configured if the auto-detection isn't sufficient.

### Kotlin 1.7.20+

For Kotlin 1.7.20+, the Kotlin plugin [supports toolchains directly](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/whatsnew1720.html#new-method-for-jvm-toolchain-configuration) and has a simplified syntax:

```kotlin
kotlin {
  jvmToolchain(17)
}
```

### Kotlin 1.5.30+

For Kotlin 1.5.30+, the Kotlin plugin [supports toolchains directly](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/whatsnew1530.html#support-for-java-toolchains):

```kotlin
kotlin {
  jvmToolchain {
    (this as JavaToolchainSpec).languageVersion.set(JavaLanguageVersion.of(17))
  }
}
```

### Kotlin Earlier Versions

Configuring the Kotlin compiler for versions prior to 1.5.30 involves using the toolchain API to determine the compiler, and passing that information to the plugin. Other compiler-based plugins may be configured in similar ways.

```kotlin
val compiler = javaToolchains.compilerFor {
  languageVersion.set(JavaLanguageVersion.of(11))
}

tasks.withType<KotlinJvmCompile>().configureEach {
  kotlinOptions.jdkHome = compiler.get().metadata.installationPath.asFile.absolutePath
}
```

Comment: Do i need to remove sourceCompatibility & targetCompatibility? Also if i want it to run with a specific java update, let's say Java 8 Update 281 instead of Java 8 Update 271, is it possible?

Comment: @jumping_monkey You can't define them at the `java { }` extension level, but you can still define them at the `JavaCompile` task level. Or use the new `release` flag on `CompileOptions`. See https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/building_java_projects.html#sec:java_cross_compilation. About the specific java update, see https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/16628.

Comment: how can i use the toolchain for all the plugins? cc @Raman

Comment: @SouravJha Depends on the plugin, but my answer describes how to use compiler metadata to set the appropriate options for your plugin(s).

Comment: I meant that for my project using Gradle as my build tool, I have the Gradle wrapper, on running the Gradle commands the plugins I have used, should use toolchain java instead of my machine's default java. Is there a global way to set compiler for all the plugins.

Comment: @Raman is it possible to do the above?

Comment: @SouravJha No, there is no "global" way to do it for plugins that do not yet understand toolchains directly (see https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/toolchains.html#sec:plugins). See my answer for how to configure a plugin manually, assuming it supports such configuration.

Comment: how do any of these answers tell gradle where the java 11 jre is located?

Comment: @johnktejik Gradle attempts to auto-detect the location via several common mechanisms (see https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/toolchains.html#sec:auto_detection). You can also define custom locations if the auto-detection isn't sufficient (see https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/toolchains.html#sec:custom_loc).

Comment: As of version 7.6 Gradle will also attempt to download Java when necessary, defaulting to the Adoptium/AdoptOpenJDK distributions.

Comment: Much better answer than the ones with higher score above. This solution allows me to be sure my app is built with the correct JDK version. Above all, Gradle automatically finds the appropriate JDK version installed on my machine (with SDKMAN! in my case) to perform the build. Much more convenient than specifying the JDK location via -Dorg.gradle.java.home=/JDK_PATH. Thank you @Raman

Answer (score 68):

If you have this problem from `Intellij IDE`, try this options

1. Set Gradle JVM Home
   [image]
2. Set the JDK version in the Project module settings
   [image]
3. Check the JDK version in the Modules
   [image]

Comment: Does this solution still work if you open a terminal and run gradle build? Or is this solution only used when using the IDE to run/compile code?

Comment: This is for the IDE

Comment: @Johann yes. This can work from some terminal uses of gradle: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67079327/how-can-i-fix-unsupported-class-file-major-version-60-in-intellij-idea/67101848#comment128424269_67101848

Comment: There is no such option in the Gradle settings in 2023.

Answer (score 31):

If you are executing using gradle wrapper, you can run the command with JDK path like following

`./gradlew -Dorg.gradle.java.home=/jdk_path_directory`

Answer (score 18):

You could easily point your desired Java version with specifying in the project level `gradle.properties`. This would effect the current project rather than altering the language level for every project throughout the system.

```
org.gradle.java.home=<YOUR_JDK_PATH>
```

Comment: didnt work.
`Value 'C:Program FilesJavajdk-11.0.8' given for org.gradle.java.home Gradle property is invalid (Java home supplied is invalid)`
Please provide examples.

Comment: escape the backslashes like so org.gradle.java.home=C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk-11.0.8

Comment: Tried something like "org.gradle.java.home=C\:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk-11.0.16.1", but it won't work. However, something like this works: "./gradlew -Dorg.gradle.java.home="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.15" build"

Comment: This may be a sensitive private information about path of the development machine. How to deal with it?

Answer (score 11):

If you are using JDK 9+, you can do this:

```
java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}

tasks.withType<JavaCompile> {
    options.compilerArgs.addAll(arrayOf("--release", "8"))
}
```

You can also see the following related issues:

- Gradle: [[Java 9] Add convenience method for `-release` compiler argument](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/2510)
- Eclipse Plug-ins for Gradle: [JDK API compatibility should match the sourceCompatibility option](https://github.com/eclipse/buildship/issues/934).

Comment: Question: why do wee need to set ```--release``` if we are already setting the ```target```?

Answer (score 10):

If you are using linux and gradle wrapper you can use following solution.

Add path to local.properties file:

```
javaHome=<path to JDK>
```

Add to your gradlew script file:

```
DIR=$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )
source $DIR/local.properties 2>/dev/null

if ! [ -z "$javaHome" ]
then
  JAVA_HOME=$javaHome
fi
```

In this solution, each developer can set his own JDK path. File `local.properties` shouldn't be included in version control system.

Comment: Bumped into the same problem as OP (being forced to meddle with old project whom the original developer has left), this is the best solution for me so far

Comment: Using another environment variable instead of writing it in the local.properties file can also do the same job.

Comment: This makes your gradlew installation work differently than in projects made by other people, adding a stumbling block for every new collaborator.

Answer (score 8):

There is one more option to follow. In your gradle tasks available in Eclipse, you can set your desired jdk path. (I know this is a while since the question was posted. This answer can help someone.)

Right click on the deploy or any other task and select "Open Gradle Run Configuration..."

[image]

Then navigate to "Java Home" and paste your desired java path.

[image]

Please note that, bin will be added by the gradle task itself. So don't add the "bin" to the path.

Comment: Don't see gradle tasks

Comment: Is this for Eclipse? If yes, please specify it in your answer.

Answer (score 7):

For windows run gradle task with jdk 11 path parameter in quotes

```
gradlew clean build -Dorg.gradle.java.home="c:/Program Files/Java/jdk-11"
```

Answer (score 6):

I added this line in my GRADLE_HOME/bin/gradle file - 
`export JAVA_HOME=/path/to/java/version`

Answer (score 6):

For Windows, open cmd and enter to your project root, then execute a command like this:

**gradlew build -Dorg.gradle.java.home="jdk_path"**

My JDK is located in this path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.5.

So, for my case, it looks like this below:

**gradlew build -Dorg.gradle.java.home="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.5"**

Additionally, if you want to specify a certain variant, you can do like this :

**gradlew assembleDebug -Dorg.gradle.java.home="E:\AndroidStudio\jre"**

This command will compile your project with **Debug** variant and output 2 apks(debug + release) in 2 folders.

Answer (score 6):

> ***gradle.properties***

```
  org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536M
    android.useAndroidX=true
    android.enableJetifier=true
    org.gradle.java.home=C\:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk-11.0.15

-------------------------------------------------------------------
```

> ***build.gradle***

```
 android {
        compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion
        ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion
        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility 11
            targetCompatibility 11
        }
        kotlinOptions {
            jvmTarget = '11'
            useIR = true
        }
        sourceSets {
            main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
        }
```

after flutter3.0 & jdk11 install these steps worked for me

Comment: Old question with the updated answer. that's great +1

Answer (score 3):

there is a Gradle plugin that download/bootstraps a JDK automatically:

https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/com.github.rmee.jdk-bootstrap

No IDE integration yet and a decent shell required on Windows.

Comment: Where "decent shell" means bash, basically. I just submitted a PR to make it work for the batch file too.

Answer (score 3):

There is a pretty simple way. You can try the following solution.

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

After updating your java version, let check Gradle current JVM's version to ensure this change was applied.

```
gradle -v
```

For more details, pls review your `gradlew` file (in Unix-like OS) or `gradlew.bat` file (in Window OS) to see how Gradle config `JAVACMD` variable.

For example

```
# Determine the Java command to use to start the JVM.
if [ -n "$JAVA_HOME" ] ; then
    if [ -x "$JAVA_HOME/jre/sh/java" ] ; then
        # IBM's JDK on AIX uses strange locations for the executables
        JAVACMD="$JAVA_HOME/jre/sh/java"
    else
        JAVACMD="$JAVA_HOME/bin/java"
    fi
    if [ ! -x "$JAVACMD" ] ; then
        die "ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: $JAVA_HOME

Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of your Java installation."
    fi
else
    JAVACMD="java"
    which java >/dev/null 2>&1 || die "ERROR: JAVA_HOME is not set and no 'java' command could be found in your PATH.

Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of your Java installation."
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

As seen in [Gradle (Eclipse plugin)](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/gradle)

[image]

http://www.gradle.org/get-started

> Gradle uses whichever JDK it finds in your path (to check, use java -version). Alternatively, you can set the JAVA_HOME environment variable to point to the install directory of the desired JDK.

---

If you are using this Eclipse plugin or [Enide Studio 2014](http://www.nodeclipse.org/enide/studio/2014/), alternative JAVA_HOME to use (set in Preferences) will be in version 0.15, see http://www.nodeclipse.org/history

Comment: Hi Paul, actually, exactly this is my problem. I want to define a different JDK for gradle-building tasks than defined in JAVA_HOME. Though, it's good to know that there will be an entry in the eclipse plugin for this :)

Comment: Standard Eclipse allows to define environment variables per launch configuration. But that is not what we try with gradle. Open an issue if you explore this question further https://github.com/Nodeclipse/nodeclipse-1/issues

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to set it once to run a specific command:

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-oracle/ gw build
```

Comment: this doesn't work for me on Windows cmd.exe

Comment: @eri0o: You'll have to do something like `set JAVA_HOME=${PATH_TO_JAVA} && gw build`

Answer (score 2):

So, I use IntelliJ for my Android project, and the following solved the issue in the IDE:

just cause it might save someone the few hours I wasted...
IntelliJ -> Preferences -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build tools -> Maven -> Gradle

and set **Gradle JVM** to 1.8
make sure you also have JDK 8 installed...

NOTE: the project was compiling just fine from the command line

Answer (score 1):

### Android Studio

File > Project Structure > SDK Location > JDK Location >

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
```

GL

[Install JDK](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14788468/5279996)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Kotlin DSL, then in `build.gradle.kts` add:

```
tasks.withType<JavaCompile> {
    options.isFork = true
    options.forkOptions.javaHome = File("C:\\bin\\jdk-13.0.1\\")
}
```

Of course, I'm assuming that you have Windows OS and `javac` compiler is in path `C:\bin\jdk-13.0.1\bin\javac`. For Linux OS will be similarly.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Gradle 4.2 . Default JDK is Java 9. In early day of Java 9, Gradle 4.2 run on JDK 8 correctly (not JDK 9).

I set JDK manually like this, in file **`%GRADLE_HOME%\bin\gradle.bat`**:

```
@if "%DEBUG%" == "" @echo off
@rem ##########################################################################
@rem
@rem  Gradle startup script for Windows
@rem
@rem ##########################################################################

@rem Set local scope for the variables with windows NT shell
if "%OS%"=="Windows_NT" setlocal

set DIRNAME=%~dp0
if "%DIRNAME%" == "" set DIRNAME=.
set APP_BASE_NAME=%~n0
set APP_HOME=%DIRNAME%..

@rem Add default JVM options here. You can also use JAVA_OPTS and GRADLE_OPTS to pass JVM options to this script.
set DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS=

@rem Find java.exe
if defined JAVA_HOME goto findJavaFromJavaHome

@rem VyDN-start.
set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\
@rem VyDN-end.

set JAVA_EXE=java.exe
%JAVA_EXE% -version >NUL 2>&1
if "%ERRORLEVEL%" == "0" goto init

echo.
echo ERROR: JAVA_HOME is not set and no 'java' command could be found in your PATH.
echo.
echo Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
echo location of your Java installation.

goto fail

:findJavaFromJavaHome
set JAVA_HOME=%JAVA_HOME:"=%


@rem VyDN-start.
set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\
@rem VyDN-end.


set JAVA_EXE=%JAVA_HOME%/bin/java.exe

if exist "%JAVA_EXE%" goto init

echo.
echo ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: %JAVA_HOME%
echo.
echo Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
echo location of your Java installation.

goto fail

:init
@rem Get command-line arguments, handling Windows variants

if not "%OS%" == "Windows_NT" goto win9xME_args

:win9xME_args
@rem Slurp the command line arguments.
set CMD_LINE_ARGS=
set _SKIP=2

:win9xME_args_slurp
if "x%~1" == "x" goto execute

set CMD_LINE_ARGS=%*

:execute
@rem Setup the command line

set CLASSPATH=%APP_HOME%\lib\gradle-launcher-4.2.jar

@rem Execute Gradle
"%JAVA_EXE%" %DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS% %JAVA_OPTS% %GRADLE_OPTS% "-Dorg.gradle.appname=%APP_BASE_NAME%" -classpath "%CLASSPATH%" org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain %CMD_LINE_ARGS%

:end
@rem End local scope for the variables with windows NT shell
if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" goto mainEnd

:fail
rem Set variable GRADLE_EXIT_CONSOLE if you need the _script_ return code instead of
rem the _cmd.exe /c_ return code!
if  not "" == "%GRADLE_EXIT_CONSOLE%" exit 1
exit /b 1

:mainEnd
if "%OS%"=="Windows_NT" endlocal

:omega
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37959153/11080293) I was able to identify that my issue was gradle picking the wrong JDK even if the JAVA_HOME was set correctly.

**My original comment:**

My OS is Linux and I have my JAVA_HOME pointing to the correct path. I have even used this command gradle build -Dorg.gradle.java.home=$JAVA_HOME to prove my point. I've installed gradle using snap in Ubuntu and I'm guessing it is using some bundled JDK.

**My solution:**

I've removed gradle using snap and then I've manually installed gradle by downloading their binaries and put it in the PATH.

My conclusion is that the gradle snap installation on Ubuntu comes bundled with some older JDK.