# How do I change the IntelliJ IDEA default JDK?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I use IntelliJ IDEA as my development environment, and Maven for dependency management.  I frequently build my project structure (directories, poms, etc) outside of IDEA and then import the project into IDEA using `Import project from external model`.  This works great, except that in my poms I specify that the maven-compiler-plugin should use JDK 1.6, and when I import, IDEA informs me that the `Language Level Changed` and that `Language level changes will take effect on project reload`, and then prompts to reload the project.  This is annoying because I always use the same JDK version.

How do I change the default JDK that IntelliJ IDEA uses, so that I don't have to reload my project every time I import a new project?

Answer (score 368, accepted):

This setting is changed in the "Structure for New Projects" dialog. Navigate to "File" -> "New Projects Setup" -> "Structure..."

[image: Selecting Structure For New Projects]

Next, modify the "Project SDK" and "Project Language Level" as appropriate.

[image: Selecting Project Language Level]

---

Previous versions of IntelliJ IDEA had this setting in "File" -> "Other Settings" -> "Default Project Structure...".

IntelliJ IDEA 12 had this setting in "Template Project Structure..." instead of "Default Project Structure..."

Comment: Jetbrains, Eclipse, Oracle etc should get together and set a standard for IDE configurations, hotkey combos etc. Then we devs could just remain productive when jumping from one IDE to another.

Comment: May I ask IntelliJ IDEA to use my %JAVA_HOME% system variable as a value of _JDK home path_? I want IntelliJ IDEA to reflect changes of JAVA_HOME sys variable automatically.

Comment: I think intellij should rename the menu entry 'file' to 'Project'. There are so many project specific things under file.

Comment: In the default window that opens when running IntelliJ IDEA (the project selector), on MacOS you can also hit `⌘` `;` to open the Project Structure for New Projects settings.

Answer (score 73):

Download and unpack a JDK archive file (.tar.gz) and add it as a SDK in the **'Project Structure'** dialog box ( <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> )

[image: jdk 9 intellij]
*click on the gif to enlarge*

Also make sure to set an appropriate 'Project language level'. I forgot to do that when creating the GIF.

Project Structure > Project > Project language level

For Java 8 set it to 8, for Java 9 set it to 9, and so on.

Comment: how to create this kind of gif?

Answer (score 58):

- I am using IntelliJ IDEA 14.0.3, and I also have same question. Choose menu **`File` \ `Other Settings` \ `Default Project Structure...`**

[image]

- Choose **`Project`** tab, section **`Project language level`**, choose level from dropdown list, this setting is **`default for all new project`**.
  [image]

Answer (score 31):

I have found out that in recent versions of IntelliJ IDEA requires Java 1.8 but is not configured by default.

We can change the path or configure from **`Project Settings`** > **`Project`** > **`Project SDK`**

here we can edit or add the JDK´s path.

(in my case the path is located in `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102`)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 21):

Change JDK version to 1.8

1. Language level File -> project Structure -> Modules -> Sources -> Language level -> 8-Lambdas, type annotations etc.
   [image]
2. Project SDk File -> project Structure -> Project 1.8
   [image]
3. Java compiler File -> Settings -> Build, Executions, Deployment -> Compiler -> Java compiler
   [image]

Comment: This does not address the *default* settings: see the accepted answer.

Answer (score 11):

One other place worth checking: Look in the pom.xml for your project, if you are using Maven compiler plugin, at the source/target config and make sure it is the desired version of Java. I found that I had 1.7 in the following; I changed it to 1.8 and then everything compiled correctly in IntelliJ.

```
<build>
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
        <configuration>
            <source>1.8</source>
            <target>1.8</target>
            <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 5):

The above responses were very useful, but after all settings, the project was running with the wrong version. Finally, I noticed that it can be also configured in the Dependencies window.
Idea 2018.1.3 File -> Project Structure -> Modules -> Sources **and** Dependencies.

Answer (score 5):

**To change the JDK version of the Intellij-IDE himself:**

Start the IDE -> Help -> Find Action

than type:

```
Switch Boot JDK
```

or (depend on your version)

```
Switch IDE boot JDK
```

Comment: In case IntelliJ doesn't start after that, edit the content of ~/Library/Preferences/IntelliJIdea2018.2/idea.jdk .  from: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360000171064-Java-10-Mac-won-t-start-up

Comment: Clarification: as of IntelliJ 2020.3.4  this action *does not seem available*; I bet it finds the startup JDK automatically, or uses the included jbr(jre?) in the IntelliJ binaries directory. 
That is, you cannot switch it.
There are _no_ actions for 'Boot', basically

Comment: @JordanGee In 2021.x you can search for this action `Choose Boot Java Runtime for the IDE...`

If the IDE crash on startup you can remove the jdk config, by removing this file `~/Library/Application\ Support/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2021.3/idea.jdk`

Answer (score 5):

I am using IntelliJ 2020.3.1 and the File > Other Settings... menu option has disappeared. I went to Settings in the usual way and searched for "jdk". Under  Build, Execution, Deployment > Build Tools > Maven > Importing I found the the setting that will solve my specific issue:

JDK for importer.

[image: IntelliJ 2020.3 Settings dialog]

Answer (score 4):

For latest version intellij, to set default jdk/sdk for new projects go to

`Configure->Structure for New Projects -> Project Settings -> Project SDK`

Comment: Where did you find "Configure"? I'm using IntelliJ 2020 and cant fint it.

Comment: @GrgKro See my answer below. I had to hunt for it but documented what I did do with a picture...

Answer (score 0):

On my linux machine I use a script like this:

```
export IDEA_JDK=/opt/jdk14
/idea-IC/bin/idea.sh
```