# IntelliJ "Invalid Keystore Format" When Importing a Project From Source

Tags: java, intellij-idea, keystore

Occasionally I see an 'Invalid Keystore Format' error when importing a project from existing source into IntelliJ.  How can I resolve this error, which prevents me from creating the project.

Answer (score 1):

This can occur when using an out-of-date JDK as your project SDK.  When prompted in the import project from existing source dialog, select a newer Java version as your project SDK.  Alternatively, if you're already selecting the latest Java SDK version available inside the import project from existing source dialog, you may have to install a newer JDK, and then add it as a project SDK via the "File" -> "Other Settings" -> "Default Project Structure" -> "Platform Settings" -> "SDKs" menu, prior to importing a project.  You can also set the default Project SDK using the answer for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18987228/how-do-i-change-the-intellij-idea-default-jdk), to avoid this problem until there is another Java update.