# IntelliJ Idea won't compile java 8 even though I selected JDK 1.8

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ide

I'm trying to work on a small project in `Java` version `8`. I installed `IntelIJ IDEA`, but unfortunately I can't get it to compile `java 8` code, such as:

```
import java.util.function.*;
```

I followed this [tutorial](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544879-Selecting-the-JDK-version-the-IDE-will-run-under?page=3), and downloaded and installed `JRE 1.8`, resulting in my About window looking like this:

[image: JRE 1.8.0_152]

However, it still does not see the `java.util.function` package, and if I run the following code:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.version"));
    }
}
```

it outputs `1.6.0_65`.

I would appreciate some insight

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18987228/how-do-i-change-the-intellij-idea-default-jdk

Comment: please, go to the project structure and show us screen. Also, type in your console `echo $JAVA_HOME` and show us output

Comment: @ArturCzopek your suggestion was really the key to my problem - it turned out that I didn't have JDK 1.8 installed and the project SDK was set to 1.6. Now it works perfectly