# Cannot resolve method 'List.of(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)'

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I've been trying to create a simple hello world application with Java and SpringBoot in IntelliJ IDEA, but I get this error and I don't know how to solve it.

I get the error at the return. Java doesn't seem to know how to resolve the `of` method that's in the `public List<String> getHelloWorld` method.

```
package com.myname.SpringApp;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import java.util.List;


@RestController
public class HelloWorldController {
    @RequestMapping("api/hello-world")
    @GetMapping
    public List<String> getHelloWorld(){
        return List.of("Hello", "World");
    }
}
```

Comment: What's your Java version?  [`List.of`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#of(E,E)) was new in Java 9.

Comment: The `List.of(..)` is available in JDK9+ as far as I know. So my assumption is you are using JDK8...

Comment: You can use `Arrays.asList` in earlier Java versions (`Collections.unmodifableList(Arrays.asList(...))`, if you're being picky).

Answer (score 19):

The overloaded [`List.of` methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/List.html#of--) were introduced in Java 9.

> **Since:**
>    9

You must be compiling with an older version. Update to Java 9 or later. [Here's how.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18987228/how-do-i-change-the-intellij-idea-default-jdk)

Answer (score 2):

You can use *Arrays.asList*.

List.of will support java 9 and above