# How to eliminate a specific error while is running maven project

Tags: java, spring, maven, jsp, tomcat

Good evening!
My question is odd but I could not run an existing maven project.

There is an error which IDE returns:
and I have a bunch of them.
I am using Intellij IDEA.
Even if I run just simple mvn install I have the same issue.
I googled but there is no positive result.

Error:(140, 74) java: diamond operator is not supported in -source 1.5
  (use -source 7 or higher to enable diamond operator)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/18987228/2970947

Answer (score 1):

IntelliJ requires you to add some properties to your pom.xml file

```
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
```

Also, check your selected SDK:

[image]

and the language level in your module settings:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer but I still have the same error. I would like to add some screenshots but I cant. I have the same settings as yours; java 1.8 and Language level - 8.

Comment: I tried to run mvn clean install but I get more than 10 errors like that:[ERROR] /Users/kirillbarsukov/Desktop/Project/src/main/java/com/project/viewer2/View6DAO.java:[218,55] cannot find symbol

Comment: I have no idea how it is possible because I downloaded that project from company's SVN repository. It means 100% that there is nothing missing and an issue is somewhere in my environment.

Answer (score 1):

As an addition to Michael W's answer. I think you also put these settings under Project?

[image: Project Settings]

And to be on the safe side, check here if the version is set correctly. Sometimes it differs with me. You can simply enter javac in the search settings.
[image: Settings]