# cannot find symbol symbol: class Base64 location: package java.util

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I followed this [tutorial](https://github.com/sarxos/webcam-capture/tree/master/webcam-capture-examples/webcam-capture-websockets) to show web cam with the help of server.

But , It not done.

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y5zig.png)

```
Error:(5, 17) java: cannot find symbol
symbol:   class Base64
location: package java.util
Error:(93, 45) java: cannot find symbol
symbol:   variable Base64
location: class WebcamWebSocketHandler
```

Why this error occurs?

```
Error:(5, 17) java: cannot find symbol
symbol:   class Base64
location: package java.util
```

line 5 `import java.util.Base64;`

```
Error:(93, 45) java: cannot find symbol
symbol:   variable Base64
location: class WebcamWebSocketHandler
```

Line 93 `base64 = new String(Base64.getEncoder().encode(baos.toByteArray()), "UTF8");`

[code](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sarxos/webcam-capture/master/webcam-capture-examples/webcam-capture-websockets/src/main/java/WebcamWebSocketHandler.java)

[error at line 93](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CvPyK.png)

I am using java 14.

How can I solve this error?

Comment: I think you must set the Intellij java to the latest version. [See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18987228/how-do-i-change-the-intellij-idea-default-jdk)

Comment: I tried this . But , it not done.