# Cannot access greenfoot.World - class file has wrong version

Tags: java, greenfoot

I try to use Intellij IDEA for Greenfoot development on Mac.
Here is a tutorial to use NetBeans with Greenfoot:
https://www.greenfoot.org/doc/running_on_netbeans

So I created my scenario in Greenfoot. Then saved it and opened it in IDEA.
I took greenfoot.jar and bluejcore.jar from application package and added these libraries to a project structure.
At this point I receive the following error:

> Error:(9, 30) java: cannot access greenfoot.World   bad class file:
> /Users/.../Greenfoot/greenfoot.jar!/greenfoot/World.class
> class file has wrong version 55.0, should be 52.0
> Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the classpath.

Some conflict with a version. However I took both jars from the Greenfoot application installed on my machine. Appreciate some help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error says, that `greenfoot.World` was compiled with Java 11 and you try to use it with a compiler supporting up to Java 8.

[Try changing the JDK](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18987229/13912132)

Comment: Is this possible to compile it somehow for Java 8?

Comment: The newest versions of Greenfoot require Java 11, so use either an older version or you are out of luck