# Intellij won't accept openjdk 15

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ide

When I try to choose  JDK for IntellijCE, it refuses to accept openJDK15.  Does anyone know how to get around this?  It keeps insisting on JDK9, which is ancient history on my machine.

This occurs even when using the instructions linked here:
[How do I change the IntelliJ IDEA default JDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18987228/how-do-i-change-the-intellij-idea-default-jdk)

Comment: Why do you need to change [IDE's boot JDK](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/switching-boot-jdk.html)?

Comment: Because it's on jdk9 and I would like to use 15.

Comment: UDE uses 11 JDK version as boot Java Runtime by default (unless you have changed it). But it is not related to the JDK you use in your project for development. You can use any JDK version for you projects: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/sdk.html#change-project-sdk

Comment: I did that. And it refuses to accept the openjdk15 JDK.

Comment: `it refuses to accept the openjdk15 JDK.` Please attach a screenshot of this error. What IDE version do you use?