# how to make gradle use a specific Java version?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle

I have java 1.4 and 1.8 installed on my machine and When importing a gradle project it complains that gradle-2.0 requires Java 2 or later to run. Your build is currently configured to use java 4.

How do i change it to use 8 instead of 4?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21212790/1091466 check this

Comment: You sure about the error message? Because IRC Java2 1.4 is a java 2 jdk. I would check the shell/bat script starting up intellij and see if it using JAVA_HOME and then see what that is pointing to, as well as the PATH environment variable.