# How to check java version when running gradle?

Tags: gradle

One of my project requires Java 1.8, but sometimes we didn't notice we are using older java so that we will get some strange errors.

I want to add the checking in `build.gradle`, so that when we run any task, it will firstly check the version, and prints error and quit immediately.

I tried to add the checking directly in `build.gradle` on the first line, but it still do some others tasks e.g. (`clean`, `compileJava`) before the checking happens, when I run:

```
$ ./gradlew
```

How to do it correctly?

Comment: Gradle build script is parsed and executed as it is. So if you put your check directly into script, not in some task, it should be executed at once. Can you share the relevant part of the build.gradle file?

Comment: @Nikem, thanks, just found there is a `buildSrc` directory under the project root, and the tasks defined in it are running before my checking code. It's fine to let them running first

Comment: @Freewind, there's no need to use `buildSrc` here. Just add the code checking version of java at the very beginning of `build.gradle` script.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

If you put the check very early in your build lifecycle (plain check in the beginning of your `build.gradle` file or in the apply method of a plugin) you shouldn't see any tasks executed.

you can use JavaVersion enum for that which is part of the gradle api:

```
if(JavaVersion.current() != JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8){
    throw new GradleException("This build must be run with java 8")
}
```

Comment: It could also be checked sooner, like in the beginning of your `settings.gradle`.

Comment: well if you want to check it really soon. put it in a init script ;-)

Comment: Sure. Note that init scripts either force you to add `--init-script your-script` to your command lines or must sit outside the project (in $HOME or $GRADLE_HOME). See https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/init_scripts.html

Answer (score 12):

The accepted answer is nice however it could be improved a little bit by making it more generic. Indeed instead of comparing the current version with an explicit version, we could rely on the value of `targetCompatibility` instead (assuming it has been set properly) as next:

```
if (JavaVersion.current() != project.targetCompatibility) {
    throw new GradleException("The java version used ${JavaVersion.current()} is not the expected version ${project.targetCompatibility}.")
}
```

Comment: And how does one set `targetCompatibility`? edit: Just found https://stackoverflow.com/a/44799256/119790

Comment: Beware that order of execution is important when checking against current project settings: Checks like the above might be used pretty early in the build file, in which case `project.targetCompatibility` might still be the current java version and the tests succeeds. That can't happen with comparing against an explicit version.