# Stop Eclipse updates on classpath and settings

Tags: java, eclipse, java-8, java-6

I upgraded to the latest Eclipse Mars.2 Release (4.5.2) and there is one issue that is driving me crazy.

Every time I refresh a project JDK version 8 is added here:

- `.classpath`, this line changes:

`<classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/jdk1.8.0_72"/>`

- `.settings/org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs`, this line changes:

`org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.compliance=1.8`

My project has been using JDK 6 for years. I have installed JDK 6 and 8 for testing purposes.

No matter if I change the project settings manually, every time I refresh the project Eclipse automatically sets version 8.

---

Even if I disable `Enable project specific settings`, when I refresh the project, that option is re enabled and the file `.settings/org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs` is created with this content:

```
eclipse.preferences.version=1
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.compliance=1.8
```

Also, in Global Preferences > Java > Compiler I set 1.6 and in Installed JREs `jdk1.6.0_43` is set as default.

This started happening after I upgrade Eclipse, so it is surely a bug. However, I would like to know if there is any workaround.

---

Other things I tried and did not work:

- Cleaning the project
- Starting Eclipse with `eclipse -clean`

Comment: is it a maven project?

Comment: @dit no, I use Gradle.

Comment: okay. have you tried to define java JDK in your Gradle properties? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18487406/how-do-i-tell-gradle-to-use-specific-jdk-version

Comment: @dit I use `sourceCompatibility = 1.6`. I'll try that and see if it helps

Comment: @dit thanks for pointing in the right direction! :) it was Gradle, they must have changed something in the Buildship plugin behaviour. Thanks!

Comment: maven has the same issue. no problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a bug but not from Eclipse, from the Gradle plugin: Buildship 1.0.9.

In case anyone has the same issue, I modified `.settings/gradle.prefs` and set the value for `connection_java_home`:

```
{
  "1.0": {
    "project_path": ":",
    ...
    "connection_java_home": "C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.6.0_43",
    ...
  }
}
```

Now, when I refreshed the project, only `.classpath` was modified but with this value:

```
<classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/
    org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/jdk1.6.0_43"/>
```

---

As @dit suggested, another option is to add the file `gradle.properties` to the project, including:

```
org.gradle.java.home=C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.6.0_43
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue and will be fixed with Buildship 1.0.10

See discussion at the end of https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=472996