# How to execute gradle plugin with different version of java

Tags: java, gradle

I am running into an issue with my gradle build script, `build.gradle`, for my *java* project. In this script I need to compile the application with *Java* 6 in order to comply with the application specifications. However, I am also using a gradle plugin that performs code analysis that needs to be run under a *Java* 8 JVM. What do I need to do in `build.gradle` or other gradle settings in order to get this plugin to use a separate *Java* JVM?

I need to do something like this as gradle tasks fail because the plugin is reporting a `Unsupported major.minor version 52.0` Error.

**Research**

I have done some invesitigation and I did see the following mentioned: 

`options.fork = true
options.forkOptions.executable = System.getenv('OTHER_JAVA')`

Where `OTHER_JAVA` is an environment variable to the other version of *Java*. However, I have not been able to get this to work for the plug-in and after some more research, it looks like this may be more limited to **compiling** with a separate version of java, not **executing**.
See: [How do I tell Gradle to use specific JDK version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18487406/how-do-i-tell-gradle-to-use-specific-jdk-version)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've pretty much answered your question yourself:

> it looks like this may be more limited to **compiling** with a separate version of java, **not executing**

Run Gradle under the Java 8 (that would mean specifying your JAVA_HOME as JDK 8), and fork the compiler for your app with Java 6 (as per your research).