# How to downgrade Java from 9 to 8 on a MACOS. Eclipse is not running with Java 9

Tags: java, eclipse

How to downgrade Java from 9 to 8 on a macOS Sierra 10.12.6(16G29) . I tried removing the Java plugin and installed Java 8, however the Java and javac version shows 9 in terminal, but In system preferences it is 8.

Comment: The version of MacOS may be relevant; consider editing & adding that to the question (not posting as a comment).

Comment: did you have a look at https://wiki.eclipse.org/Configure_Eclipse_for_Java_9?

Answer (score 413):

You don't need to down grade. You can run more than one version of Java on MacOS. You can set the version of your terminal with this command in MacOS.

```bash
# List Java versions installed
/usr/libexec/java_home -V

# Java 11
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 11)

# Java 1.8
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8)

# Java 1.7
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.7)

# Java 1.6
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.6)
```

You can set the default value in the .bashrc, .profile, or .zprofile

Comment: Thanks a lot, that helped me! It's a shame that Java Control Panel in MacOS doesn't expose settings like this.

Comment: Could you please elaborate your answer? What does `/usr/libexec/java_home -v 11` mean?

Comment: Doing `export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8)` and `export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8.0_211)` doesn't solve my problem. Already restarted my terminal also.

Comment: I keep getting "JAVA_HOME: inconsistent type for assignment". And the java version doesn't change. Any clue how to fix this?

Comment: Thanks this helping me to run SonarQube on my Mac. Because SonarQube doesn't support Java 11+

Answer (score 195):

This is how I did it. You don't need to delete Java 9 or newer version.

**Step 1:**  Install Java 8

You can download Java 8 from here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html

**Step 2:** After installation of Java 8. Confirm installation of all versions.Type the following command in your terminal.

```
/usr/libexec/java_home -V
```

**Step 3:** Edit .bash_profile

```
sudo nano ~/.bash_profile
```

**Step 4:** Add 1.8 as default. (Add below line to bash_profile file).

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8)
```

Now Press CTRL+X to exit the bash. Press 'Y' to save changes.

**Step 5:** Reload bash_profile

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

**Step 6:** Confirm current version of Java

```
java -version
```

Comment: Is it possible to change javaws version in same way? Because java -version reports that it changed, but javaws still runs newest available.

Answer (score 15):

If you have multiple Java versions installed on your Mac, here's a quick way to switch the default version using Terminal. In this example, I am going to switch Java 10 to Java 8.

```
$ java -version
java version "10.0.1" 2018-04-17
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.3 (build 10.0.1+10)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.3 (build 10.0.1+10, mixed mode)

$ /usr/libexec/java_home -V
Matching Java Virtual Machines (2):
    10.0.1, x86_64: "Java SE 10.0.1"    /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-10.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home
    1.8.0_171, x86_64:  "Java SE 8" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_171.jdk/Contents/Home

/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-10.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home
```

Then, in your .bash_profile add the following.

```
# Java 8
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_171.jdk/Contents/Home
```

Now if you try java -version again, you should see the version you want.

```
$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_171"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_171-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.171-b11, mixed mode)
```

Answer (score 7):

As it allows to install more than one version of java, I had install many 3 versions unknowingly but it was point to latest version "11.0.2"

I could able to solve this issue with below steps to move to "1.8"

```
$java -version
```

openjdk version "11.0.2" 2019-01-15
OpenJDK Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.2+9)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.2+9, mixed mode)

```
cd /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines
ls
```

jdk1.8.0_201.jdk    jdk1.8.0_202.jdk    openjdk-11.0.2.jdk

```
sudo rm -rf openjdk-11.0.2.jdk
sudo rm -rf jdk1.8.0_201.jdk
ls
```

jdk1.8.0_202.jdk

```
java -version
```

java version "1.8.0_202-ea"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-ea-b03)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.202-b03, mixed mode)

Comment: I'd avoid removing files on your system. Instead just redirect the `$JAVA_HOME` env variable.

Answer (score 5):

Old question but just had that problem /dumb jira having problems with java 10/ and didn't find a simple answer here so just gonna leave it:

`$ /usr/libexec/java_home -V` shows the versions installed and their locations so you can simply remove `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/<the_version_you_want_to_remove>`. Voila

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the [offical Oracle Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/install/installation-jdk-and-jre-macos.htm#JSJIG-GUID-F9183C70-2E96-40F4-9104-F3814A5A331F) there are two relevant paths you need to delete in case you wan't to remove a Java installation.

Path 1 is the JRE - installation path:  `/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/` 
Path 2 is the JDK - installation path:  `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines`

**JRE Steps:**
Change directory via Terminal to the Path 1.

```
cd /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/
```

Remove JavaAppletPlugin.plugin

```
sudo rm -rf JavaAppletPlugin.plugin
```

**JDK Steps:**
Do the Steps under JRE Steps
Change directory via Terminal to the Path 2.

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines
```

Take a look at all installations at this folder

```
ls
```

Remove any installations in this folder.

```
sudo rm -rf /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-(...).jdk
```

After uninstalling you are ready to go for a fresh installation. Just [download](https://www.oracle.com/de/java/technologies/javase-downloads.html) you're version of choice and install it.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution might be to install Java 8 in parallel to Java 9 (if not still still existant) and specify the JVM to be used explicitly in `eclipse.ini`. You can find a description of this setting including a description how to find `eclipse.ini` on a Mac at [Eclipsepedia](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini)

Answer (score 1):

**FOR MAC USERS only**

Change for both JRE and JDK version

Path 1 is the JRE - installation path: /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/
Path 2 is the JDK - installation path: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines

JRE Steps:
Change directory via Terminal to the Path 1.

cd /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/
Remove JavaAppletPlugin.plugin

sudo rm -rf JavaAppletPlugin.plugin
JDK Steps:
Do the Steps under JRE Steps
Change directory via Terminal to the Path 2.

**step 1**

**/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines**

Take a look at all installations at this folder

**step 2**

**ls** // to list all files in folder

Remove any installations in this folder.

**step 3**

**sudo rm -rf /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/yourjdkName.jdk**

After uninstalling you are ready to go for a fresh installation. Just download you're version of choice and install it.

best solution for this

Comment: This worked for me thank you. I couldn't get the method of editing .bash_profile to work.

Answer (score -3):

You can remove "JavaAppletPlugin.plugin" found in Spotlight or Finder, then re-install downloaded Java 8.

This will simply solve your problem.