# Hadoop's command start-dfs.sh is showing a strange error

Tags: java, macos, hadoop, hdfs

When i try to run below command, an error pops up

Alis-Mac:hadoop-2.7.3 naziaimran$ sbin/start-dfs.sh

Below is the error,

```
2018-06-05 01:04:31.424 java[1879:21215] Unable to load realm info from SCDynamicStore
18/06/05 01:04:31 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Starting namenodes on [localhost]
localhost: starting namenode, logging to /Users/naziaimran/Desktop/hadoop-2.7.3/logs/hadoop-naziaimran-namenode-Alis-Mac.out
localhost: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
localhost:  at org.apache.hadoop.util.StringUtils.<clinit>(StringUtils.java:80)
localhost:  at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.HdfsServerConstants$RollingUpgradeStartupOption.getAllOptionString(HdfsServerConstants.java:80)
localhost:  at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.<clinit>(NameNode.java:249)
localhost: Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: begin 0, end 3, length 2
localhost:  at java.base/java.lang.String.checkBoundsBeginEnd(String.java:3107)
localhost:  at java.base/java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1873)
localhost:  at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.<clinit>(Shell.java:51)
localhost:  ... 3 more
localhost: starting datanode, logging to /Users/naziaimran/Desktop/hadoop-2.7.3/logs/hadoop-naziaimran-datanode-Alis-Mac.out
Starting secondary namenodes [0.0.0.0]
0.0.0.0: starting secondarynamenode, logging to /Users/naziaimran/Desktop/hadoop-2.7.3/logs/hadoop-naziaimran-secondarynamenode-Alis-Mac.out
0.0.0.0: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
0.0.0.0:    at org.apache.hadoop.util.StringUtils.<clinit>(StringUtils.java:80)
0.0.0.0:    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SecondaryNameNode.main(SecondaryNameNode.java:667)
0.0.0.0: Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: begin 0, end 3, length 2
0.0.0.0:    at java.base/java.lang.String.checkBoundsBeginEnd(String.java:3107)
0.0.0.0:    at java.base/java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1873)
0.0.0.0:    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.<clinit>(Shell.java:51)
0.0.0.0:    ... 2 more
2018-06-05 01:04:48.170 java[2203:22211] Unable to load realm info from SCDynamicStore
18/06/05 01:04:48 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
```

I am stuck here for days now, any help will be highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Have you tried installing and running Hadoop from Homebrew? By the way, Hadoop does not yet support Java 9 and above

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that Hadoop 2.7 is incompatible with Java 9/10.
I had the same issue and solved it by downgrading to Java 8.

Check the answer by VK321 here, if you are unsure about how to downgrade and get it to work:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/48422257/5181904