# What Java version does React Native work with?

Tags: java, react-native, gradle

I get an error * What went wrong:
Could not determine java version from '10.0.1'.

I want to downgrade to an older version of Java rather than upgrade Gradle. I want to know what is the newest version that React Native works with?

Comment: I'd try Java 8, worked for me when I got similar error messages. Relevant to this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48422257/4039886

Answer (score 2):

I had to upgrade from version 8 to support latest android sdk

```
buildToolsVersion = "30.0.2"
minSdkVersion = 21
compileSdkVersion = 31
targetSdkVersion = 31
ndkVersion = "23.1.7779620"
```

I ended up with Java 11.

If you are using [sdkman](https://sdkman.io), run

```
sdk install java 11.0.11.hs-adp
```

Comment: do you know where i could find a helper to upgrade our react-native project to utilize the new java? did you need many native file changes?

Comment: https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper

Answer (score 1):

java 8, other versions below java10 should work as well

Answer (score -14):

Java and React Native has no direct relationship . They are two different things. React Native lets you build mobile apps using only JavaScript. And it lets you build mobile apps for Android devices. Android devices uses an SDK which is based on the Java platform.

React Native apps will work on Android 4.1 (API 16) upwards.

Android 8.1 Oreo (API 27) is the latest stable version available . And Android 9.0 P (API 28) is the upcoming version which is still in beta

Really the fastest way to get around this error is to use JDK 8

Comment: But you *can* integrate native (android, Java) code

Comment: Not a great answer. You do need JAVA installed on your machine or you will get "Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of your Java installatio" trying to run npm run android.