# Not able to create/import Gradle (4.3) project in Eclipse Oxygen and Java 9

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, project

I am trying to develop project in Gradle and Spring Boot using Eclipse Oxygen. I have latest Gradle version. My system in MAC 10.10.2 (14C109) OS X Yosemite.

Following are details over the issue. While creating project, Gradle user home directory is coming 'unknown' at the last page I have attached image of it:

[image: Image of last step]

```
$gradle -version
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 4.3.1
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2017-11-08 08:59:45 UTC
Revision:     e4f4804807ef7c2829da51877861ff06e07e006d

Groovy:       2.4.12
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.6 compiled on June 29 2015
JVM:          9.0.1 (Oracle Corporation 9.0.1+11)
OS:           Mac OS X 10.10.2 x86_64
```

**The erro coming in eclipse**
The following will be send to: Eclipse

REPORT

```
anonymousId         a9e8db44-ee8e-4012-9e8e-302774ee01b3
name                Taushif
email               
comment             
eclipseBuildId      4.7.1.M20171009-0410
eclipseProduct      org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
javaRuntimeVersion  9.0.1+11
osgiWs              cocoa
osgiOs              MacOSX
osgiOsVersion       10.10.2
osgiArch            x86_64
severity            UNKNOWN


STATUS

pluginId            org.eclipse.ui
pluginVersion       3.109.0.v20170411-1742
code                0
severity            4
message             Unhandled event loop exception
fingerprint         2d8cf2c7a5898a92b35629394884ede6

Exception:java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not determine java version from '9.0.1'.
     at org.gradle.api.JavaVersion.toVersion(JavaVersion.java:70)
     at org.gradle.api.JavaVersion.current(JavaVersion.java:80)
     at org.gradle.internal.jvm.UnsupportedJavaRuntimeException.assertUsingVersion(UnsupportedJavaRuntimeException.java:29)
     at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ConnectorServices.checkJavaVersion(ConnectorServices.java:57)
     at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ConnectorServices.createCancellationTokenSource(ConnectorServices.java:39)
     at org.gradle.tooling.GradleConnector.newCancellationTokenSource(GradleConnector.java:95)
     at org.eclipse.buildship.core.util.progress.ToolingApiJob.<init>(ToolingApiJob.java:57)
     at org.eclipse.buildship.core.workspace.internal.SynchronizeGradleBuildsJob.<init>(SynchronizeGradleBuildsJob.java:46)
     at org.eclipse.buildship.core.workspace.internal.SynchronizeGradleBuildsJob.forSingleGradleBuild(SynchronizeGradleBuildsJob.java:122)
     at org.eclipse.buildship.core.workspace.internal.DefaultGradleBuild.synchronize(DefaultGradleBuild.java:58)
     at org.eclipse.buildship.ui.wizard.project.ProjectImportWizardController.performImportProject(ProjectImportWizardController.java:167)
     at org.eclipse.buildship.ui.wizard.project.ProjectCreationWizard.performFinish(ProjectCreationWizard.java:180)
     at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.finishPressed(WizardDialog.java:778)
     at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.buttonPressed(WizardDialog.java:417)
     at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog.lambda$0(Dialog.java:619)
     at org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionListener$1.widgetSelected(SelectionListener.java:81)
     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:249)
     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:86)
     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4257)
     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1502)
     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1525)
     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1510)
     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.notifyListeners(Widget.java:1314)
     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4081)
     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3698)
     at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:818)
     at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:794)
     at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.WizardHandler$New.executeHandler(WizardHandler.java:269)
     at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.WizardHandler.execute(WizardHandler.java:290)
     at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerProxy.execute(HandlerProxy.java:291)
     at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.E4HandlerProxy.execute(E4HandlerProxy.java:92)
     at HIDDEN.HIDDEN(HIDDEN:-1)
     at HIDDEN.HIDDEN(HIDDEN:-1)
     at HIDDEN.HIDDEN(HIDDEN:-1)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
     at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:55)
     at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invokeUsingClass(InjectorImpl.java:305)
     at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invoke(InjectorImpl.java:239)
     at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.invoke(ContextInjectionFactory.java:132)
     at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceHandler.execute(HandlerServiceHandler.java:152)
     at org.eclipse.core.commands.Command.executeWithChecks(Command.java:494)
     at org.eclipse.core.commands.ParameterizedCommand.executeWithChecks(ParameterizedCommand.java:487)
     at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceImpl.executeHandler(HandlerServiceImpl.java:210)
     at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.LegacyHandlerService.executeCommand(LegacyHandlerService.java:390)
     at org.eclipse.ui.internal.actions.CommandAction.runWithEvent(CommandAction.java:151)
     at org.eclipse.ui.internal.actions.CommandAction.run(CommandAction.java:161)
     at org.eclipse.ui.actions.NewWizardDropDownAction.run(NewWizardDropDownAction.java:175)
     at org.eclipse.jface.action.Action.runWithEvent(Action.java:473)
     at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:565)
     at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.lambda$5(ActionContributionItem.java:436)
     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:86)
     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4257)
     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1502)
     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1525)
     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1510)
     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.notifyListeners(Widget.java:1314)
     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4081)
     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3698)
     at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1150)
     at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
     at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1039)
     at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:153)
     at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:680)
     at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
     at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:594)
     at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:148)
     at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:151)
     at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
     at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
     at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
     at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
     at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
     at HIDDEN.HIDDEN(HIDDEN:-1)
     at HIDDEN.HIDDEN(HIDDEN:-1)
     at HIDDEN.HIDDEN(HIDDEN:-1)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
     at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:653)
     at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:590)
     at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1499)


BUNDLES

name                org.eclipse.buildship.core
version             2.1.2.v20170807-1324

name                org.eclipse.buildship.ui
version             2.1.2.v20170807-1324

name                org.eclipse.core.commands
version             3.9.0.v20170530-1048

name                org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable
version             1.6.100.v20170515-1119

name                org.eclipse.core.databinding
version             1.6.100.v20170515-1119

name                org.eclipse.core.runtime
version             3.13.0.v20170207-1030

name                org.eclipse.e4.core.commands
version             0.12.100.v20170513-0428

name                org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts
version             1.6.0.v20170322-1144

name                org.eclipse.e4.core.di
version             1.6.100.v20170421-1418

name                org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench
version             1.5.1.v20170815-1446

name                org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt
version             0.14.101.v20170710-1119

name                org.eclipse.equinox.app
version             1.3.400.v20150715-1528

name                org.eclipse.equinox.launcher
version             1.4.0.v20161219-1356

name                org.eclipse.jface
version             3.13.1.v20170810-0135

name                org.eclipse.swt
version             3.106.1.v20170926-0519

name                org.eclipse.ui
version             3.109.0.v20170411-1742

name                org.eclipse.ui.ide.application
version             1.2.0.v20170512-1452

name                org.eclipse.ui.ide
version             3.13.1.v20170822-1526
```

**NOTE**
Not sure what helped, but this get resolved. I did 2 things:-
1.I ran gradle command from terminal in workspace of eclipse.
2.Updated Buildship gradle integration from eclipse ide.

Comment: You have Eclipse Oxygen.1 (4.7.1), but Java 9 is only supported since Oxygen.1a (4.7.1a).

Comment: I have Oxygen.1a (4.7.1a), but am facing the same error. Were you able to find a resolution?

Comment: Tried many other ways like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18487406/how-do-i-tell-gradle-to-use-specific-jdk-version, this one works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

The Buildship team has released a milestone 2.2 build that fixes this issue.

You can either install the milestone 2.2 in eclipse. Help > Install New Software... > Work with: http://download.eclipse.org/buildship/updates/e47/milestones/2.x > Select most recent version > Finish

Or you can wait until the official 2.2 release of Buildship and update the Buildship plugin.

Milestone Announcement: https://discuss.gradle.org/t/buildship-2-2-milestone-is-now-available/24551

Answer (score 0):

You have to install the [Buildship from Eclipse Marketplace](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/buildship-gradle-integration) and also changed the build script (to fix the gradle eclipse plugin with unexpected behavior to Java 9):

```
eclipse {
    jdt.file.withProperties { props ->
       props.put('org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.codegen.targetPlatform', '9')
       props.put('org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.source', '9')
       props.put('org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.compliance', '9')
    }
    classpath.defaultOutputDir = new File(buildDir, "classes/main")
}
```