# Gradle project refresh failed: Error:The supplied javaHome seems to be invalid. I cannot find the java executable. Tried location: ../jre/bin/java

Tags: java, android-studio, gradle, refresh, project

Dears,
I just moved from Windows7 to Linux Mint. I can't sync the gradle as I always get:

> Error:The supplied javaHome seems to be invalid. I cannot find the
>   java executable. Tried location: /media/Android Studio
>    Preview/jre/bin/java

Noting that:
1- /media/Android Studio Preview/jre/bin/java is the path for old android stuido used in windows. i don't know how current android studio is trying this path.

2-
$ which java

/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.9.0-openjdk-i386/bin/java

3-I am using the old SDK ( which already used before in win7).

4-
$java -version

openjdk version "9-internal"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 9-internal+0-2016-04-14-195526.buildd.src)
OpenJDK Server VM (build 9-internal+0-2016-04-14-195526.buildd.src, mixed mode)

5-
echo $JAVA_HOME

/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.9.0-openjdk-i386/bin/java

6-JDK location is the new android studio installation in linux:
/local/android-studio/jre

Thanks to help.

Comment: Try adding this line to your `gradle.properties` file: `org.gradle.java.home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.9.0-openjdk-i386/bin/java`

Comment: Didn't solve the problem. and i noticed that "org.gradle.java.home" is gray. however, sdk.dir and ndk.dir are blue.

Comment: Anything from this answer help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/21212790/3280538

Comment: Also , Validate & restart didn't help

Comment: the error changed to:    Error:Java home supplied via 'org.gradle.java.home' is invalid. Invalid directory: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.9.0-openjdk-i386/bin/java

Comment: I've one doubt, my laptop is X64, but this Mint version is 32. do you think this is the cause?

Comment: When I installed Linux Mint 64 bit, every thing went ok. Thanks flakes for your help and suggestions.