# gradlew uses wrong Java version

Tags: java, android, macos, gradle

I am working on an android application using Kotlin. I am running a kotlin linter through command line ./gradlew klint.
But it gives me an error:

> Gradle 4.4 requires Java 7 or later to run. You are currently using Java 6.

When I check the project structure, I am using the embedded JDK.
I also updated android studio to latest version. I do not know how to update the embedded JDK to latest version.

`java version`

> "1.6.0_65" Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_65-b14-468) Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.65-b04-468, mixed mode)

`which java` - /usr/bin/java

`echo $PATH` - `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/username/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools`

`echo $JAVA_HOME` - empty

Comment: what is the output of `java -version`?

Comment: java version "1.6.0_65"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_65-b14-468)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.65-b04-468, mixed mode)

Comment: I'm fairly sure the emdedded JDK is at least Java 7. `gradlew` uses PATH anyway, not the embedded Java of Android Studio

Comment: Please [edit] the question with output of `which java` and `echo $PATH` and `echo $JAVA_HOME`

Comment: Why don't you just install Java on your OS? You are not required to use the embedded JDK, nor can I find any documentation that recommends it.

Comment: @cricket_007 Yes t i will ry to install on my OS and then check

Comment: have you see that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21212790/2801860

Comment: Did you run `/usr/libexec/java_home -V` ? Then just download the latest from Oracle.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> A copy of **the latest OpenJDK** comes bundled with Android Studio 2.2 and higher, and this is the JDK version we recommend you use for your Android projects.

https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/studio-config.html#jdk

This however, is only for building your apps **within Android Studio**, not from the terminal with `gradlew`, otherwise, it'll use whatever is on your OS's `$PATH` variable.

In order to use the embedded JDK, you at least need to set `JAVA_HOME`, for example on Linux/Mac,

```
$ export JAVA_HOME=/path/to/AndroidStudio/jdk  # TODO: Find this
$ ./gradlew
```

My recommendation, however, is to use the mechanism for your OS for installing Java.

For easy Java library management (on Linux & Mac), you can try using [`sdkman`](http://sdkman.io/)

Comment: Thankyou for your help to point out that gradlew uses java from system not from android studio

Comment: i had to use 
set JAVA_HOME=/path/to/jdk
for windows

Answer (score 9):

gradle.properties can be updated to point to the embedded JDK that comes with Android Studio in Mac OS:

org.gradle.java.home=/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home

Comment: for windows: C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/jre

Comment: It might have changed, but mine was at `/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home/` (no `/jdk/` folder)

Answer (score 1):

The issue is resolved by adding :

```
/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin
```

at the start of the PATH variable . What i have found is that: There are three java locations.

1. Java that comes with mac (`/usr/bin/java`)
2. Java downloaded from oracle . ( `/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin`)
3. Java embedded with Android Studio (`/Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/`)

In my case the `gradlew` was always using the java from MAC (point number 1).
So when i added the " java dowloaded from oracle (point 2)" at the start of path variable it started using the one from oracle and my gradlew command ran.