# Which installed JDK used during Gradle build process

Tags: java, gradle, version, gradlew

This was my output of `gradle -v` (in a project using the wrapper):

```
$ ./gradlew -v

------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 5.0
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2018-11-26 11:48:43 UTC
Revision:     7fc6e5abf2fc5fe0824aec8a0f5462664dbcd987

Kotlin DSL:   1.0.4
Kotlin:       1.3.10
Groovy:       2.5.4
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.13 compiled on July 10 2018
JVM:          11.0.1 (Oracle Corporation 11.0.1+13-LTS)
OS:           Linux 3.10.0-862.11.6.el7.x86_64 amd64
```

See especially this line:

```
JVM: 11.0.1 (Oracle Corporation 11.0.1+13-LTS)
```

I was wishing to switch to OpenJDK 11. So select it as you can see below:

```
# alternatives --config java

There are 4 programs which provide 'java'.

  Selection    Command
-----------------------------------------------
*  1           /usr/java/jdk-11.0.1/bin/java
 + 2           /usr/local/jdk-11.0.1/bin/java
   3           /usr/java/jre1.8.0_191-i586/bin/java
   4           /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_191-amd64/jre/bin/java

Enter to keep the current selection[+], or type selection number: 2

# java -version
openjdk version "11.0.1" 2018-10-16
OpenJDK Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.1+13)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.1+13, mixed mode)
```

But there is no difference in `gradle -v` output. So I searched the web and find some ways (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18487406/how-do-i-tell-gradle-to-use-specific-jdk-version)):

1. Editing `gradle.properties` file
2. Using `-Dorg.gradle.java.home` command line option
3. Editing `build.gradle` file

I used the first two ways. Both worked (to test I switched to `JDK 8` and then run `build` task. The task failed due to some new features in my codes that aren't supported by Java 8). But **the result of `gradle -v` remained unchanged still**! Even using the second way:

```
# ./gradlew -Dorg.gradle.java.home=/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_191-amd64 -v

------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 5.0
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2018-11-26 11:48:43 UTC
Revision:     7fc6e5abf2fc5fe0824aec8a0f5462664dbcd987

Kotlin DSL:   1.0.4
Kotlin:       1.3.10
Groovy:       2.5.4
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.13 compiled on July 10 2018
JVM:          11.0.1 (Oracle Corporation 11.0.1+13-LTS)
OS:           Linux 3.10.0-862.11.6.el7.x86_64 amd64
```

---

**So the question is *how to check which JDK version is used by Gradle during `build` process?***

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can add a task that prints what you need when executed (Kotlin DSL):

```
tasks {
    val j by creating {
        doLast {
            println(System.getProperty("java.home"))
        }
    }
}
```

Groovy DSL:

```
tasks.register("j") {
    doLast {
        println System.getProperty("java.home")           
    }
}
```

Then executing `./gradlew j`:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk/jre
```

Why could `gradlew` use another JVM? Take a look at this script and you'll see that it uses `JAVA_HOME` variable to search for JVM. So probably the version from your `PATH` is not the same, that `JAVA_HOME` is pointing to.

Answer (score 7):

*I find an alternative way (except [@madhead answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53763654/5318303)) **just for when you use a Gradle daemon**:*

First, find `PID` of daemon by running `gradlew --status` (see [here](https://docs.gradle.org/5.0/userguide/gradle_daemon.html#sec:status) for more information). Sample output:

```
   PID STATUS   INFO
 11432 IDLE     5.0

Only Daemons for the current Gradle version are displayed. See https://docs.gradle.org/5.0/userguide/gradle_daemon.html#sec:status
```

Then use `PID` to find which `JDK` is used:

```
ll /proc/<PID>/exe
```

Sample output:

```
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 0xy 0xy 0 Jan  5 04:03 /proc/11432/exe -> /usr/local/jdk-11.0.1/bin/java
```

---

On Windows:

```
> wmic process where "processId=<PID>" get Name, ProcessID, ExecutablePath
```

Sample output:

```
ExecutablePath                                     Name      ProcessId
C:\Program Files\Java\openjdk-11.0.1\bin\java.exe  java.exe  11432
```

Comment: if there's anyone struggling with this on macOs: `ps xuwww -p <PID>`. that should also give you the command (including the java path) used by gradle