# gradlew: Couldn't determine java version from '11.0.1'

Tags: java, android-gradle-plugin

I am using Mac OS (Mojave) and Android Studio 3.2.1. I am trying to use Fastlane tool for screenshot capturing.

When I run: `./gradlew assembleDebug assembleAndroidTest` 
I get the following error:

> - FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
>   - What went wrong:
>
>   Could not determine java version from '11.0.1'.
>
>   - Try:
>
>   Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

My java version according to `java --version`is

> java 11.0.1 2018-10-16 LTS Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9 (build
>   11.0.1+13-LTS) Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.1+13-LTS, mixed mode)

How do I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a git issue for this exact problem and the solution for it is:

https://github.com/openrndr/openrndr/pull/25/commits/684240c4da0c6223d0171e3f3273ee48b9094772

Answer (score 1):

You can not use Java 11 for Android development

Please use a JDK 8.

If you have both JDK 8 and 11 installed, you can tell gradle to use one: [How do I tell Gradle to use specific JDK version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18487406/how-do-i-tell-gradle-to-use-specific-jdk-version)