# FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.(for flutter)

Tags: flutter, intellij-idea

i'm trying to create my first flutter app but when i run it it gives me this error

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not open settings remapped class cache for b4ieilm7vkknhwvoai8y4gzba (C:\Users\Emre.gradle\caches\5.6.2\scripts-remapped\settings_1vci5hthrjrgkv26gortq0d7w\b4ieilm7vkknhwvoai8y4gzba\settings8410a2d21ed2f87c8a0398566330ee52).

  > Could not open settings generic class cache for settings file 'C:\JavaDemos\sea_ok\android\settings.gradle' (C:\Users\Emre.gradle\caches\5.6.2\scripts\b4ieilm7vkknhwvoai8y4gzba\settings\settings8410a2d21ed2f87c8a0398566330ee52).
  >   BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '*BuildScript*' Unsupported class file major version 57
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Answer (score 0):

Look at the answer here: [Flutter build error for the first time :Could not open settings remapped class cache for 7yvt6la2007dno98lt3rzbguf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60142464/flutter-build-error-for-the-first-time-could-not-open-settings-remapped-class-c)

The problem is most likely the Java version you have installed.

Comment: i have gradle 6.4.1 but how can i use it in vs code. its automatically downloading 5.6.2 but its not support jdk 13. i want to use with version 6.4.1 how can i do

Comment: @EmreÇil Can you run "flutter doctor -v" in your terminal and post the output?