# How to fix the ''module java.base does not "opens java.io" to unnamed module '' error in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

**Background**

1. I started my first project in android studio to get familiar with Android programming.
2. I am following this [tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/creating-project), in which

- I created a new project Empty Activity, without any change
- It is supposed to simulate a simple app that shows "Hello World" message

**Problem Description**
But every time I try to run and build (I want to emulator as of now), I get the following error message.

```
Unable to make field private final java.lang.String java.io.File.path accessible:
Unable to make field private final java.lang.String java.io.File.path
accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.io" to unnamed module @42760a00
```

***Here is my config set-up***:

1. Android Gradle plugin version: 4.2.1
2. Gradle Version: 7.0.1 (changed to fix another issue I had while syncing the Gradle ("Gradle sync failed: Unsupported class file major version 60") and based discussion on this [forum](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-266799) as quoted below)

> Andrey Dernov commented 14 Apr 2021 00:18 Please use Gradle 7.0 or JDK
> less than 16 version for importgin and building the project (Settings
> (Preferences on macOS) | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools |
> Gradle | Gradle JVM option).

3. JDK: 16.0.1

Any suggestion or idea?

Answer (score 328):

The solution from [GitHub](https://github.com/fluttercommunity/flutter_workmanager/issues/287#issuecomment-893476072) has worked for me. It was no need to downgrade Java JDK. Just changed gradle version in gradle-wrapper properties to 7.1.1 (6.x does not support java 16), and adding the following line in gradle.properties:

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536M \
--add-exports=java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED \
--add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED \
--add-opens=java.base/java.lang.reflect=ALL-UNNAMED \
--add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED \
--add-exports=jdk.unsupported/sun.misc=ALL-UNNAMED
```

Comment: Thanks, man! it works for me, I just copied the code and paste it to android/gradle.properties

Comment: It worked for me too. But could you explain what exactly this line do?

Comment: it was not the correct answer, though it gives me and idea to change the gradle class path, and viola it worked

Comment: For ButterKnife compiler, also add `--add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.util=ALL-UNNAMED`

Comment: Worked for me after changing properties to 7.3.3 and making the change in jvmargs

Comment: Work also for Mac M1

Comment: its worked for me. i have to some changes in AndroidManifest.xml too. like in intent filter add properties android:exported="true". Thanks

Comment: @lortschi It worked but I want to know what caused the problem.

Comment: It worked and I don't care what caused the problem!

Comment: Worked, really useful answer (should be the top answer).

Comment: This worked for me, but I really want to know why. Can anyone explain this?

Comment: You can add the same vm options to spring boot config in Idea and it will work.

Answer (score 194):

You must be using a JDK version that is not supported by the Gradle Version.
( There is no need to downgrade )

1-Check your JDK Version from *C:\Program Files\Java*. In My Case, It's JDK-17.0.2

2-Check The Respective Gradle version for your JDK
https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/compatibility.html

3-Open **gradle-wrapper.properties** from *.\android\gradle\wrapper\*
[image: Screen Shot for gradle-wrapper.properties file] and change the **distributionUrl** to your required gradle version

**e.g.** for JDK 17

```
distributionUrl = https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.3-all.zip
```

4-Open **build.gradle** from *.\android\build.gradle*
[image: classpath in build.gradle file]
and change the plugin in the class path to the one according to your gradle version

**e.g.**

```
classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.2") for Gradle 6.7.1+
classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.0") for Gradle 7+
```

Check the Compatible Plugin for your Gradle version at
https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#updating-gradle

5-run `npx react-native run-android`

Comment: Great answer, Thanks, You need to update some numbers and it will be up-to-date

Comment: In the last code block, did you mean Gradle 6.7.1+ and Gradle 7+?

Comment: @TWiStErRob Yes it's Gradle, bad I thought I fixed it. Updated!

Comment: any update to this answer since JDK has been replaced with JBR now?

Comment: I have no C:\Program Files\Java directory

Answer (score 41):

**I think I found the solution.**

If you are importing an old project you are likely to face this error.

Basically you made your old project with lower JDK versions and now you have higher JDK versions installed currently in your system.

You should avoid higher JDK versions for building older projects.

1. Basically Download JDK 8 (1.8) and install it.
2. change environment variable (write JDK 8 path to environment variable)
3. Then change your project structure and write JDK 8 path to JDK location.

[image]

4. invalidate caches and restart android studio.
5. build your project and it should work.

---

If you got the following error:

```
Error:Cannot fit requested classes in a single dex file.Try supplying a main-dex list. # methods: 72477 > 65536
```

Then add the following dependency in your app.gradle file:

```
 // multidex
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
```

then you need to enable multidex in your app.gradle file.

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 30

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.convenient.easymeasure"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 30
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
```

Answer (score 26):

has worked for me in Macbook Air M1 Apple Silicon. you no need to downgrade or uninstall Java JDK.

in my case Just changed gradle version in gradle-wrapper.properties to 7.2
like this :

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.2-all.zip
```

and adding the following line in gradle.properties:

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536M --add-exports=java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.lang.reflect=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports=jdk.unsupported/sun.misc=ALL-UNNAMED
```

related solution on [github](https://github.com/fluttercommunity/flutter_workmanager/issues/287#issuecomment-893476072)

Answer (score 15):

Add this line in your gradle.properties file.

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536M --add-exports=java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.lang.reflect=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports=jdk.unsupported/sun.misc=ALL-UNNAMED
```

Comment: it's important to note that using these flags might expose your application to potential security risks or compatibility issues. It's recommended to understand the implications and risks associated with modifying JVM behavior and only use these configurations if necessary to resolve specific issues. Additionally, consider updating your code or dependencies to adhere to best practices and avoid relying on these flags for normal operations.

Answer (score 11):

Run `Flutter doctor`, if there´s an error indicating that the java bundled can´t be found (specially if you have Android Studio version **Artic Fox**), run this commands if using Mac:

1. cd /Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/jre
2. ln -s ../jre jdk
3. ln -s "/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin" jdk

Comment: I was fighting with Android Studio Artic Fox (for 2 days) to build and run an android emulator. Flutter doctor was all good. I tried JDK 11, 15, 16. I tried adding variables to .bash_profile. I installed and tried older emulators. Nothing was working. Your commands worked. Can you explain why Andrey?

Comment: @lopes710 the reason is because the Artic Fox version have a different location for the java library, the commands from above is for giving the correct path. This error usually happens when you come from an older version of Android Studio to Artic Fox

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. If on mac, and after updating Android Studio to Arctic Fox 2020.3.1 (patch 4) from the previous version (4.2.2)

Comment: Same here, I was wasting my time installing and changing versions of Java.
- macOS Ventura.
- Android Studio Dolphin (2021.3.1).

Answer (score 11):

In my case the following steps did the trick:

1. Changing the gradle verion in gradle-wrapper.properties to:

   ```
   distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.3.3-all.zip
   ```
2. Changing build gradle and google services classpath version in build.gradle to:

   ```
   dependencies {
       classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.1'
       classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.5'
   }
   ```

Answer (score 8):

I was able to fix it by upgrading grade project settings using Android Studio which replaced
`classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.2")` with         `classpath('com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3')` in `android/build.gradle`

Comment: This replacement solved my issue in my Flutter project.

Answer (score 6):

Downgrade your Java version.It works for me

[image]

Comment: I work on multiple `react-native` projects. one project requires `Java 17` and another one `Java 11`. when I used `Java 17` for the project which actually requires `Java 11` then i faced this error. When I reverted back to `Java 11` then issue resolved.

Comment: @ThinkAndCode Yes! I was also facing this error when I used `java 17 `

Comment: How am I supposed to know what version to downgrade to?

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue with a Flutter 2 project after updating Android Studio to electric eel. I was still able to build the android project, but `flutter run` on the Flutter project would cause this issue. [lortschi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69179997/1540350) was the key, but it was missing one more entry to make it work, so my final gradle.properties looks like this now:

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536M \
--add-exports=java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED \
--add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED \
--add-opens=java.base/java.lang.reflect=ALL-UNNAMED \
--add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED \
--add-exports=jdk.unsupported/sun.misc=ALL-UNNAMED \
--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code=ALL-UNNAMED
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

I was very skeptical, but it worked.

Answer (score 5):

For those having these issues with the latest Android Studio - Electric Eel version, and other canaries and preview releases, note that the bundled `jre` directory in the Android Studio installation folder is now renamed to `jbr`

(This answer came from [eja](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1258130/eja)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75119315/8371825) on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51281702/unable-to-find-bundled-java-version-on-flutter).)

To resolve this, just create a sym link `jre` -> `jbr` and Flutter won't complain.

On Linux

```
cd ~/android-studio/ && ln -s jbr jre
```

Windows (check installation folder)

```
cd C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
mklink /D "jre" "jbr"
```

or

```
New-Item -ItemType SymbolicLink -Path .\jre -Target .\jbr
```

Mac OS

```
cd /Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents
ln -s jbr jre
```

---

Note that if you are running a preview release, the default installation directory might be different, e.g. on Linux it would be

```
~/android-studio-preview/
```

Answer (score 5):

This is a known issue by Gradle when running tests with Java 17 with Test Distribution enabled

Add this to your build.gradle (.kts version available at the link below)

```
tasks.named('test', Test) {
    jvmArgs(
        '--add-opens', 'java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED',
        '--add-opens', 'java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED'
    )
}
```

See https://docs.gradle.com/enterprise/test-distribution/#accessing_jdk_internal_classes_from_your_tests

See original github issue https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/18647

Comment: Replace 'test' with the name of your task. If you have to open `java.io`, add it to the `jvmArgs` list. If you have more than one test task (for example, for multiple build variants) you can use `tasks.withType(Test)` instead of `tasks.named`.

Answer (score 5):

In my case, my **error was happened when I'm using**:

`Gradle version = 6.5` & `Gradle JDK version = 17.0.6` in `Android Studio Giraffe (Stable)`

You could check the Gradle version in the `gradle-wrapper.properties` file, on this line:

`distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.5-bin.zip`

And check JDK version on:

`File > Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Build Tools > Gradle > Gradle JDK`

**To fix this error, you need to pick JDK version that is compatible with your Gradle Version**. You could check the compatibility in here:

https://developer.android.com/build/releases/gradle-plugin#updating-gradle

> I pick `JDK 11.0.18` for `Gradle version 6.5` (a lower JDK version compared to my current JDK)

In summary, choosing the compatible JDK version is the answer for this error.

Comment: One more option: do an AGP update via AGP upgrade assistance.

Answer (score 4):

I downloaded 2 JDK [jdk-17.0.1](https://jdk.java.net/17/) and [jdk-11.0.13](https://www.oracle.com/in/java/technologies/javase/jdk11-archive-downloads.html) and add below line on gradle.properties

```
org.gradle.java.home=C\:\\Program Files (x86)\\Java\\jdk-11.0.13
```

Also go to Android Studio (Arctic Fox)-> Project Structure -> Gradle setting and choose JDK version

Comment: Did every other possible solution mentioned none helped, only this!
Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If you are importing an old project you may get this error

1. Download JDK 8 (1.8) and install it.
2. Change your project structure and write JDK 8 path to the JDK location.

some screenshots for reference (Android Studio Flaming version)
(sorry, couldn't em images)

[file -> project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qGfJ5.png)

[SDK location -> Gradle Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sLY3s.png)

[Gradle JDK  choose download JDK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9sJcr.png)

[Choose version 1.8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y1yTj.png)

[After download choose gradle jdk to 1.8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zdqif.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I thought your answer was clear. Helped me, at least. Sometimes you just need some hand-holding with screenshots to sort things out. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Installing JDK 1.8.0 and setting JAVA_HOME path to JDK 1.8.0's folder in environment variables worked for me.

Comment: JDK 1.8 no longer has active support, it only has security support (for a little while longer) and I would not recommend using it anymore. There are newer versions available. See also https://endoflife.date/java

Answer (score 2):

Had same problem with Flutter.
I uninstalled Android Studio and Android SDK and reinstalled everything and upgraded Flutter, without success.

Then I created a new Flutter project and copied the sources from the old one, and this time it worked.

Answer (score 2):

This is a [known issue when using Gson and reflection for parsing Json](https://github.com/google/gson/issues/1979). Updating your Android Gradle Plugin version to 7.0.0+ and the error should go away.

Answer (score 2):

To Flutters, just by deleting Android folder and running flutter create . on the project root fix it as well

Comment: Dude, thanks !! This solution worked for me

Answer (score 2):

1.ext.kotlin_version = '**1.8.0**'

2.replace this classpath '**com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2**' with your    build gradle version in dependencies.

3.replace distributionUrl=**https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5-all.zip** in gradle wrapper properties.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem at java 17, when I try to connect on JMS queue. It was solved adding the follow JVM options:

```
--add-exports=java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED 
--add-opens=java.base/java.lang.reflect=ALL-UNNAMED 
--add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED 
--add-exports=jdk.unsupported/sun.misc=ALL-UNNAMED
```

In my case, just one line was enough:

```
--add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED
```

Answer (score 2):

[image]

CHange the Gradle version of your project. It's worked for me

Answer (score 1):

I also face this issue in Android Studio after Migrating Java JDK 17

```
tasks.withType(Test) {
    jvmArgs('--add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED')
}
```

https://docs.gradle.com/enterprise/test-distribution/#accessing_jdk_internal_classes_from_your_tests

Comment: In which gradle file we have to add this exactly? app? module?

Comment: Project build.grade file not app model build.gradle file

Answer (score 0):

You must be using JDK-16, use the version below JDK-16, in my case, I downgrade to JDK-11 and it worked for me.

Comment: Downgrading only delays problems, it doesn't solve them.

Answer (score 0):

Just added from another solution

If you have later version installed, and your project is using older version. Don't forget to check in terminal which jdk is used.

In my case my project using JDK 15. And terminal using 18. So i uninstall the other version and leaving the proper version (in my mac, just delete another jdk directory in `/Libray/Java/JavaVirtualMachine`)

Answer (score 0):

**Windows user:**

Go to C:\Users\arpan.gradle\caches and delete all the gradle cache.

then,

Go to "C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio" there you will see jbr and jre folder then copy the content of jbr and paste the content into jre folder.
ss:
[image]
and run flutter doctor again and run your App.

Answer (score -1):

run

```
sudo update-alternatives --config
```

java and select a minor version of java .

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

## Steps To Solve

### 1. Gradle.properties

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5-all.zip
```

### 2. Java version

choose java version 17 or any compatiable

### 3. Gradle Project

choose kotlin version and gradle miniume version

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}
```

Comment: This isn't helpful in any possible way.

Answer (score -2):

Check if JDK is installed or not configure your SDK also and try again
you can download JDKfrom [Java SE](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-downloads.html)

Comment: Yes they are both set-up and configured in project structure section

Answer (score -5):

**Note**: this is basically a solution for old project to run is successfully.

After I updated **`jdk to 18`** then I got the error mentioned in the question. So I downgraded to jdk11, and this fixed my issue

To install jdk11 please run this command in windows 10:   `choco install openjdk11`. Hope this will fix your problem.

To run the above command you might have to install `chocolatey` and add it to path environment variable. Chocolatey is a dependency manager for windows 10.

Here is link to a guide:

https://community.chocolatey.org/packages/openjdk11

Comment: You mention both jdk 18 and 11 here, that's a bit confusing?

Comment: @SimonForsberg I have updated answer hope this solve your problem. more clearly you need to install jdk 11

Comment: Downgrading does not seem like a good idea.