# How to make field private final java.lang.String java.io.File.path accessible

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a big problem with an old project (Android Studio) of mine that I can no longer run on my new pc. How can I solve this problem?

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'.
> Unable to make field private final java.lang.String java.io.File.path accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.io" to unnamed module @387a8b67
```

Comment: What Java version (JRE/JDK) do you have installed? I would not recommend to install a version higher than 11. For an old project it can make sense to install Java 8 and use it for building the project.

Comment: I think you will find your answer here. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67782975/how-to-fix-the-module-java-base-does-not-opens-java-io-to-unnamed-module/68259155#68259155](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67782975/how-to-fix-the-module-java-base-does-not-opens-java-io-to-unnamed-module/68259155#68259155)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix the ''module java.base does not "opens java.io" to unnamed module '' error in Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67782975/how-to-fix-the-module-java-base-does-not-opens-java-io-to-unnamed-module)

Comment: Had same problem with Flutter. I uninstalled Android Studio and Android SDK and reinstalled everything and upgraded Flutter, without success. Then I created a new Flutter project and copied the sources from the old one, and this time it worked.

Answer (score 55):

You must be using JDK-16 which isn't supported yet, use the version below JDK-16, for example, I am using JDK-11 and it worked for me.

Comment: Supported by what? It is fully released according to https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-downloads.html

Comment: Jdk 15 worked for me, I got this problem in Flutter 2.8.1.

Comment: Correct ! and you can also use openjdk 14

Comment: this works for me with jdk 19 https://stackoverflow.com/a/72395717/5293521