# Unable to make field private final java.lang.String java.io.File.path accessible Qt Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, compiler-errors

I am trying to run my android program in Qt however I am getting the following error:

```
Execution failed for task ':processDebugManifest'.
> Unable to make field private final java.lang.String java.io.File.path accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.io" to unnamed module @13d72a22
```

I tried different versions of jdk and gradle however nothing helps.

Gradle version: 7.4.2
JDK version: 18

Comment: I get the same error with openjdk version "18.0.1" 2022-04-19 and Gradle 7.3.3.

Answer (score 75):

## Answer for Flutter Devs

I ran into this error in IntelliJ while trying to build a Flutter app for Android. I was updating an app I had worked on almost a year ago so the `com.android.tools.build:gradle` dependency in android/build.gradle was way out of date.

Fixed by changing dependency to this:

```
 classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.1'
```

Comment: This is valid also for native Android. Thanks!

Comment: that's worked for me too

Comment: upgrade to latest gradle version, it's now 7.4.2. In future 8.x.x, 9.x.x

Comment: Yeah worked for me too, for flutter project i did in 2022.

Answer (score 35):

Adding `--add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED` to your `JAVA_OPTS` environment variable or the `org.gradle.jvmargs` gradle property will resolve this issue with Java 18.

Here is the full `org.gradle.jvmargs` gradle property value that I'm using:

```
org.gradle.jvmargs = -Xmx2048M -Dkotlin.daemon.jvm.options\="-Xmx2048M" --add-exports=java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.lang.reflect=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports=jdk.unsupported/sun.misc=ALL-UNNAMED
```

Another option is to downgrade to JDK 17. I downgraded to openjdk version "17.0.3" 2022-04-19 and did not get the error.

Comment: worked like a charm!
openjdk 19.0.1 2022-10-18

Comment: worked on my java 19.0.2 2023-01-17

Answer (score 16):

I just figured out the solution
All I did is to add

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=--add-opens java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED
```

to the `gradle.properties` file

See this link : [How to solve InaccessibleObjectException ("Unable to make {member} accessible: module {A} does not 'opens {package}' to {B}") on Java 9?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76207178/15721679)

Comment: Please don't post the same answer to multiple posts or post answers that [already exist for the said question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72395717/10871900).

Comment: thank you for your comment, I tried to mention the answer related to this problem, in which I did answered before

Comment: If two questions are asking the same, you can flag one as a duplicate of another. Aside from that, there is already an answer saying the same for this question.

Comment: Solved for me, thanks! Also important to re-sync with gradle files after changing that, cf: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72448223/android-studio-error-cannot-find-runner-for-app

Comment: thanks you @chesterbr, but android studio can do the re-sync automatically, if it is diabled you need to do that yourself

Comment: yes it worked for me on flutter @AbdeldjalilChougui

Comment: Worked for me! I don't know what @dan1stiscrying is talking about, this is a much better answer than the one he linked. Thank you Abdeldjalil Chougui for posting this.

Answer (score 12):

The Java version is too high, downgrading will solve this problem.

You can do it with following the breadcrumbs below:

File->Project Structure->SDK Location->Gradle Settings->Gradle JDK

Answer (score 5):

Just doing an update to the project dependencies fix this.

`File > Project Structure > Suggestions`

Answer (score 3):

I got this weird error in IntelliJ when trying to build an Android project. I think the core reason was me changing the JDK version that Gradle uses in Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> Gradle and Gradle JVM down there at the bottom. I tried increasing that to fix something else and got this error. Just changing back to the exact version I always used seemed to fix it. This is kind of a terrible answer but I'm going to post it anyway, it might help someone.

Answer (score 1):

After Flutter 3.16 imperative apply is deprecated
[Deprecated imperative apply of Flutter's Gradle plugins](https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/flutter-gradle-plugin-apply)

> In Flutter 3.16, support has been added for applying these plugins
> with Gradle’s declarative plugins {} block (also called the Plugin
> DSL) and it is now the recommended approach. Since Flutter 3.16,
> projects generated with flutter create use the Plugin DSL to apply
> Gradle plugins. Projects created with versions of Flutter prior to
> 3.16 need to be migrated manually.

in android/app/build.gradle
replace

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"
```

with

```
plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    id "kotlin-android"
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
}
```

and in android/settings.gradle
replace this

```
include ':app'

def localPropertiesFile = new File(rootProject.projectDir, "local.properties")
def properties = new Properties()

assert localPropertiesFile.exists()
localPropertiesFile.withReader("UTF-8") { reader -> properties.load(reader) }

def flutterSdkPath = properties.getProperty("flutter.sdk")
assert flutterSdkPath != null, "flutter.sdk not set in local.properties"
apply from: "$flutterSdkPath/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/app_plugin_loader.gradle"
```

with

```
pluginManagement {
    def flutterSdkPath = {
        def properties = new Properties()
        file("local.properties").withInputStream { properties.load(it) }
        def flutterSdkPath = properties.getProperty("flutter.sdk")
        assert flutterSdkPath != null, "flutter.sdk not set in local.properties"
        return flutterSdkPath
    }
    settings.ext.flutterSdkPath = flutterSdkPath()

    includeBuild("${settings.ext.flutterSdkPath}/packages/flutter_tools/gradle")

    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }

    plugins {
        id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin" version "1.0.0" apply false
    }
}

plugins {
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-plugin-loader" version "1.0.0"
    id "com.android.application" version "7.3.0" apply false
}


include ':app'
```

and don't forget to update the Kotlin Gradle plugin to version 1.5.20 or higher.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I modified my gradle.properties file, since I had more than one flag to set for org.gradle.jvmargs

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=--add-opens java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED -Xmx2048m -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

You can't simply add more than one instance of org.gradle.jvmargs
This is a whole lot better than changing jdk to address something that does not require it.

Answer (score 0):

Downgrading the JDK version from 17 to 11 works for me.
Note: Do not forget to set the path for the JDK for respective platforms.

Answer (score 0):

I fix it by check the JDK Version

```bash
javac -version
```

Downgrading the JDK version from 17 to 11 like this in bash_profile
source bash_profile then build

```bash
export JAVA_HOME="/Users/{$YOURNAME}/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/corretto-1.8.0_382/Contents/Home"

export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

Answer (score 0):

i am getting this error

> Unable to make field private final java.lang.String java.io.File.path accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.io" to unnamed module @28da2d6f

just change the gradle settings to 1.8 correto

Answer (score -1):

For Flutter :

I downloaded 2 JDK jdk-17.0.1 and jdk-11.0.13 and add below line on `gradle.properties`

**For Android** :

```
org.gradle.java.home=C\:\\Program Files (x86)\\Java\\jdk-11.0.13
```

**For Mac :**

```
org.gradle.java.home=/Applications/Android Studio 2.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home
```