# Android Studio error: Cannot find runner for app

Tags: android, react-native

Trying to run an old app but it is not running properly. It recognizes there is an Android module and it finds the Android Gradle build script. When I go to run and edit the configuration this is the error I get.

[image]

Comment: error says AndroidManifest.xml doesn't exist or has incorrect root tag

Answer (score 21):

Try running "Sync Project with Gradle Files". You can find this option in the Top Left under "File". After the Sync is complete try running the App again.

Comment: Thanks! Ran into the same issue and this solved it.

Comment: No matter how many times I run into this...