# How to prevent gradle.properties from being overwritten in Cordova Android?

Tags: cordova, cordova-android

In a Cordova (11.0.0) project, when building for the Android `("cordova-android": "^10.1.2")` platform, I'm getting this error from gradle(7.4.2): `Unable to make field private final java.lang.String java.io.File.path accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.io" to unnamed module`.

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72395717/278403) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72395755/278403) it's related to Java 18 and the issue can be fixed by adding some properties to gradle.properties.

The file requiring editing is `platforms/android/gradle.properties` and it is [recommended](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/#setting-gradle-properties) that this file is modified using the `before_build` hook script.

I have done that and confirmed that my script correctly copies my version of gradle.properties. However something is subsequently overwriting that with the default version of the file.

How do I prevent my version of the file being overwritten by the default version?

Comment: For anyone who found this question because of the Java error. Solving that issue just reveals further Java and Gradle version related issues and the only way I could fix that was by reverting to a previous java version. I had to go back to Java 15.