# Flutter can not run to emulator

Tags: java, android, flutter

I'm having problem to run my flutter project to emulator. It says like this:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'.
> Unable to make field private final java.lang.String java.io.File.path accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.io" to unnamed module @5b642bd3

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 19s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Can somebody please help me, because it's been couple of days to find the way for this and having got any.

Comment: What Flutter version are you using? What is the Gradle version?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to make field private final java.lang.String java.io.File.path accessible Qt Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72323063/unable-to-make-field-private-final-java-lang-string-java-io-file-path-accessible)

Comment: Yes it works, thank you for your help. First I change the gradle version to 7.4.1, but still got an error in kotlin version. Then I change the kotlin version to .1.9.22, but still got an error in app targeting android 12, then I add android:exported="true" in androidmanifest.xml. Finally my app works fine.. Thank you for your help..