# I try to install react native and Build failed

Tags: react-native, android-studio

I try to install react native and Build failed. Why?

Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Try the new cross-platform PowerShell https://aka.ms/pscore6

PS C:\Users\stefa\Desktop\REACT\better> npx react-native run-android
info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disae it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
Jetifier found 863 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 12 workers...
info Starting JS server...
info Installing the app...

> Task :app:processDebugMainManifest FAILED
> 11 actionable tasks: 11 executed

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'.

> Unable to make field private final java.lang.String java.io.File.ph accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.io" to unnamed mule @49c3ac54

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --infor --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get fullnsights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 8s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android devepment environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-sup.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevrverPort=8081

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'.

> Unable to make field private final java.lang.String java.io.File.ph accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.io" to unnamed mule @49c3ac54
> get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 8s

```
at makeError (C:\Users\stefa\Desktop\REACT\better\node_modules\execa\index.js:174:9)
at C:\Users\stefa\Desktop\REACT\better\node_modules\execa\index.js:278:16
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
at async runOnAllDevices (C:\Users\stefa\Desktop\REACT\better\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:109:5)
at async Command.handleAction (C:\Users\stefa\Desktop\REACT\better\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js:192:9)
```

info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
PS C:\Users\stefa\Desktop\REACT\better>

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix the ''module java.base does not "opens java.io" to unnamed module '' error in Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67782975/how-to-fix-the-module-java-base-does-not-opens-java-io-to-unnamed-module)

Answer (score 1):

This is most probably due to the JDK being lower than JDK11.
Try Installing JDK11 by opening your project in Android Studio and then following these steps:

1. Open Settings and go to the Build, deployment.. option and click on the arrow to reveral Build option, click on the Build Option.

[image: Step 1]

2. Click on the drop down list next to `Gradle JDK:` under Gradle projects.

[image: Step 2]

3. Select Download JDK from the list and select Azul and JDK Version 11.

[image: Step 3]

4. Click OK and wait for it to download and confirm the updated Java/JDK is selected and press Apply followed by OK.

[image: Step 4]

Comment: can you accept the answer it it fixed it for you @port baggage

Comment: unfortunately, it does not work