# Fix: React Native App error: "Task :app:processDebugMainManifest FAILED" with jdk17

Tags: android, react-native, build, environment

I had problems setting up the updated environment for app development with RN.

openjdk version "17.0.1" / node 16+

If you're having the same problem, here's how to solve it:

Error **Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'.**

[image: problem]

Answer (score 1):

For java 16 or 17, just add line in **/android/gradle.properties**

#Fix bug java 17
org.gradle.jvmargs=--add-opens java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED
[image: solution]

Comment: This solved the issue for JDK 17+.

Answer (score 1):

it took me a while to get to this direct answer, everything from react-native is hard to find.

I'm use **jdk16**, and just add line in */android/gradle.properties* works!

Comment: Nice, worked to you too!

Answer (score 1):

Follow this answer i gave a few days ago:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/71007143/15421728

React Native and Gradle Version supported by the latest version of React Native does not support JDK below 11 and above 11.

You need go to Android Studio and download the Temurin/OpenJDK 11 or Azul 11 depending upon your system arch (if you are on the new M1 Mac you will need to download the aarch version).

clean and rebuilding should work after that.