# How can I fix this error with ButterKnife in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, butterknife

**Building succeeds, but running on an emulator fails with this message in the console:**

> Cause: superclass access check failed: class butterknife.compiler.ButterKnifeProcessor$RScanner (in unnamed module @0x65e8e2f6) cannot access class com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeScanner (in module jdk.compiler) because module jdk.compiler does not export com.sun.tools.javac.tree to unnamed module @0x65e8e2f6

**What I've tried:** Removing Butterknife from Gradle, syncing, adding back, syncing again. Removing the Butterknife lib completely which doesn't produce this error on-compile, but obviously fails to compile due to missing Butterknife.

**My environment:** Butterknife 10.2.3 Android Grade Plugin Version: 7.1.2 - Gradle Version: 7.2 - Android Studio Bumblebee

I've read that this error happens with other libraries in some rare cases that seem unrelated to mine and I still haven't found a solution. I'm aware the Butterknife is deprecated and I should migrate to ViewBinding, but that's a big task to convert this entire project to at the moment. Thanks!

Comment: i hope you do find an answer for this, seems like a mostly legitimate question, but in the time it takes you to find an answer you could potentially have fully implemented viewbinding already :)

Comment: @a_local_nobody That is an ironically true point and probably what I will end up doing. Trying to get lucky here lol

Comment: that's fine, just thought it was worth pointing out because this isn't a complicated change, just one which would take time, so i figured it would be worth pointing out, while you wait you might as well start, you'll have to do this eventually anyway, might as well be productive

Comment: @a_local_nobody You've inspired me. I think I will lol thanks!

Answer (score 79):

Some of the sun libraries needs to be made visible for the newer Java compilers.  See [this answer for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69179997/8524).  I added the following to our `gradle.properties` file and it fixed the problem. (We use Butterknife and Realm, and needed the below three packages added. (You might get away without "javac.code" for just Butterknife))

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1920M \
--add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree=ALL-UNNAMED \
--add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code=ALL-UNNAMED \
--add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.util=ALL-UNNAMED
```

Answer (score 23):

I faced this issue just after updating android Studio to Android Studio Flamingo | 2022.2.1, my project was using embeded jdk, i fixed using simple steps

1. https://www.oracle.com/pk/java/technologies/javase/jdk11-archive-downloads.html
2. Download JDK 11 for your desired OS
3. Install it
4. Android Studio-> File -> Project Structure -> SDK Location -> Click on Gradle Settings (blue hightlighted text)  -> Select the jdk 11 with 11.0 something version name from list
5. Run The Project
6. Boom! it's works

Answer (score 15):

You should compile with a different jdk, I was compiling with a jdk which was too advanced. Reverting it to jdk11 solved it for me

Comment: I ended up upgrading a lot of the project to the latest (it was pretty outdated) and resolved it. Thank you for your response.

Comment: reverting it jdk 11 for older project showing this error 
algorithm-hmacpbesha256 not availble

Answer (score 14):

Try adding the following code to the app build.gradle(project level) inside android section {}

```
android{
    tasks.withType(JavaCompile).configureEach{
    options.fork = true
    opti ons.forkOptions.jvmArgs +=[
    '--add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree=ALL-UNNAMED', 
    '--add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code=ALL-UNNAMED', 
    '--add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.util=ALL-UNNAMED']
}
```

In gradle.properties file,

```
android.nonFinalResIds=false
```

for example

```
android {
    namespace = "com.xp.vrsr"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.interact.vrsrilanka"
        minSdk 24
        targetSdk 34
        versionCode 4
        versionName "1.3"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    tasks.withType(JavaCompile).configureEach{
        options.fork = true
        options.forkOptions.jvmArgs +=[
                '--add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree=ALL-UNNAMED',
                '--add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code=ALL-UNNAMED',
                '--add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.util=ALL-UNNAMED']
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
        // but continue the build even when errors are found:
        abortOnError false
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi,
It works on my system. But how it works? Where you find this idea? Can you explain it?

Comment: Hey, It worked for me as well. I'm guessing this is just a bypassing of unmatched jdk versions

Comment: Hey, It worked for me as well Thank You.

Comment: Where to add this in `build.gradle` file ?

Comment: worked for me just add this at the end or on root

Comment: Perfect solutions for me.

Answer (score 5):

Using ideas from answers above and using Android Studio: File | Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Gradle.
Gradle JDK -> Android Studio default JDK (version 11.0.13 ...)

On Windows, to build from terminal, also had to add

```
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre
```

To the File | Settings | Terminal | Environment variables

Comment: Please mention your answer is for Windows.

Comment: Simply adding another JDK in the Gradle JDK options fixed this issue for me. No need to edit Windows environment variables.

Answer (score 5):

Step 1: gradle.properties add

```
android.nonFinalResIds=false
```

Step 2: app build.gradle add

```
tasks.withType(JavaCompile).configureEach{options.fork = true
options.forkOptions.jvmArgs +=[
'--add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree=ALL-UNNAMED', 
'--add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code=ALL-UNNAMED', 
'--add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.util=ALL-UNNAMED']}
```

Answer (score 5):

I just got that issue when opening my old project with the latest Android Studio Flamingo and wasted around 3 hours. After I have **set the project JDK to 11** then rebuild the project. It solved the issue well.

[image]

Comment: Yeah in my case I had the same issue and changing it to jdk 11 solved it.

Answer (score 4):

Please use JDK 11. though we are setting the Gradle JDK as jdk11 or correto 11, Android studio is not recognizing that.

Solution:

1. in your terminal type `java --version` to see it if is showing as JDK 11
2. If the version is not JDK 11, then set the `JAVA_HOME` env variable `export JAVA_HOME=/Users/${echo $USER}/documents/Android\Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home`
3. in your terminal type `java --version` to see it if is showing as JDK 11.

Comment: Gradle won't allow that. It now says:"Android Gradle plugin requires Java 17 to run. You are currently using Java 11."

Comment: Same happened with me.

Answer (score 2):

please add this line in build.gradle(:app) file.

android {
tasks.withType(JavaCompile).configureEach {
options.fork = true
options.forkOptions.jvmArgs += [
'--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree=ALL-UNNAMED',
'--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code=ALL-UNNAMED',
'--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp=ALL-UNNAMED',
'--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.file=ALL-UNNAMED',
'--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main=ALL-UNNAMED',
'--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.model=ALL-UNNAMED',
'--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.parser=ALL-UNNAMED',
'--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing=ALL-UNNAMED',
'--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.util=ALL-UNNAMED',
'--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.jvm=ALL-UNNAMED',
]
}
}

Answer (score 1):

Deleting the folder .gradle from the folder C:\Users\yourUser.gradle\ fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

```
 tasks.withType(JavaCompile).configureEach {
    options.fork = true
    options.forkOptions.jvmArgs += [
            '--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree=ALL-UNNAMED',
    '--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code=ALL-UNNAMED',
    '--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp=ALL-UNNAMED',
    '--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.file=ALL-UNNAMED',
    '--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main=ALL-UNNAMED',
    '--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.model=ALL-UNNAMED',
    '--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.parser=ALL-UNNAMED',
    '--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing=ALL-UNNAMED',
    '--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.util=ALL-UNNAMED',
    '--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.jvm=ALL-UNNAMED',
    ]
}
```

[reference image](https://prnt.sc/lsxzpdc7qx2L)

add the following confguration line in your gradle file and Update your **gradle plugin version to 8.0.1** and **gradle version to 8.1.1**

Answer (score 0):

please add this line in gradle propertise file.

First you change this line

org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m

To

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1920M \
--add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree=ALL-UNNAMED \
--add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code=ALL-UNNAMED \
--add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.util=ALL-UNNAMED
```

after steps follow working fine in my project.