# Build failed while trying to install an app using react native

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio

I tried to run the react-native run-android through my React Project. After that, I got an error like the following.

[full](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BQh6O.png)

[Error in the terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rcCSQ.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using a JDK version that is not supported by the Gradle Version.
Try to update Gradle or to downgrade JDK.
And I think this question is a possible duplicate of [How to fix the ''module java.base does not "opens java.io" to unnamed module''](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67782975/how-to-fix-the-module-java-base-does-not-opens-java-io-to-unnamed-module)