# Chronicle queue version 25 and JDK17

Tags: java, java-17, chronicle, chronicle-queue

I have a chronicle queue version 5.25ea12 and I receive the following error

at net.openhft.chronicle.core.internal.ClassUtil.getSetAccessible0Method(ClassUtil.java:32)
at net.openhft.chronicle.core.internal.ClassUtil.(ClassUtil.java:13)
at net.openhft.chronicle.core.Jvm.getField(Jvm.java:541)
at net.openhft.chronicle.core.Jvm.maxDirectMemory0(Jvm.java:906)
at net.openhft.chronicle.core.Jvm.(Jvm.java:145)

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: module java.base does not open java.lang.reflect to unnamed module @566776ad
at java.base/java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles.privateLookupIn(MethodHandles.java:279)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
... 20 more

I'm trying to run the application under JDK17 and with the given parameters

-Dio.netty.tryReflectionSetAccessible=true --add-exports=java.base/jdk.internal.ref=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports=jav
a.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED  --add-exports=jdk.unsupported/sun.misc=ALL-UNNAMED  --add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.file=ALL-UNNAMED  --add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac=ALL-UNNAMED  --add-opens=java.base/java
.lang=ALL-UNNAMED  --add-opens=java.base/java.lang.reflect=ALL-UNNAMED  --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED  --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED  --add-opens=java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Comment: also related - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73107319/not-using-java-modules-but-getting-module-related-exception

Comment: @Naman I'm using the given parameters but the result is the same java -jar <jar_file> --add-exports=java.base/jdk.internal.ref=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports=java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports
=jdk.unsupported/sun.misc=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.file=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.la
ng.reflect=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED