# how to solve the error below on android studio

Tags: java, xml, android-studio, java-io

> Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'.
> Unable to make field private final java.lang.String java.io.File.path accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.io" to unnamed module @7c5f1dac
> Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix the ''module java.base does not "opens java.io" to unnamed module '' error in Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67782975/how-to-fix-the-module-java-base-does-not-opens-java-io-to-unnamed-module)