# Apache gobblin build failed

Tags: gobblin

I'm new to gobblin. I try to build a distribution using master branch of the [project](https://github.com/apache/incubator-gobblin). I'm getting bellow error while following the instruction.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* Where:
 Script '/incubator-gobblin/gradle/scripts/globalDependencies.gradle' line: 44 
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating script.
Cannot invoke method getURLs() on null object
```

What could be the reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Current Gobblin build scripts use features that are present in JDK 8, but were removed in newer JDK versions. Gradle can use the latest JDK installed on your machine, e.g. JDK 13. As a result, the build process can fail.

As a workaround, you can [tell Gradle to use JDK 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18487406/how-do-i-tell-gradle-to-use-specific-jdk-version).

For example, on Windows, this can be achieved by making a change in gradle.properties (given that you have jre1.8.0_202 installed):

```
org.gradle.java.home=C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_202
```