# Flutter error Kotlin could not find the required JDK tools

Tags: java, android, flutter, gradle, sdk

I first created a new flutter project.

But I got this error:

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'.
> Kotlin could not find the required JDK tools in the Java installation 'C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_261' used by Gradle. Make sure Gradle is running on a JDK, not JRE.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 33s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

I also tried this method, but it didn't work.

[image]

Comment: maybe the jdk needs to be updated?

Answer (score 17):

### Step1:

I added the following line to the gradle.properties file

`org.gradle.java.home=C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_261` your jdk version

### Step2:

add the following line to gradle-wrapper.properties file

to the address => `\flutter_app\android\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties`

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.3-all.zip
```

Answer (score 5):

I got this error when my JRE updated, but my JDK didn't. After I downloaded and installed the updated JDK, the error went away.

Here is a link to the JDK download: https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/javase-jdk8-downloads.html

Answer (score 0):

One of these two methods should help you:

1. In `gradle.properties` in the `.gradle` directory in your `HOME_DIRECTORY` set `org.gradle.java.home=/path_to_jdk_directory`

**OR:**

2. In your `build.gradle`

```
compileJava.options.fork = true
compileJava.options.forkOptions.executable = '/path_to_javac'
```

[answer taken from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21212790/12026622)

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution to this what my issue resolved

1. Just go to your project Android folder in flutter project
2. Open gradle.properties File and add line ==>
   org.gradle.java.home=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13.0

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13.0 - This is Your JDK location in your PC Please check if JDK not installed then first install JDK and provide specific JDK location . Thanks

Answer (score -2):

upgrade java jdk then go to

```
file -> project structure -> project setting -> project change "project sdk"
```

to the latest JDK