# Flutter project don't run on Android emulator, (its work on ios emulator)

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, visual-studio-code

my laptop - MacBook Pro late 2021 (with mi pro CPU)

when I open new project its run on my iPhone emulator
but when I try to run the flutter project on my android emulator its make error

Launching lib/main.dart on sdk gphone64 arm64 in debug mode...
lib/main.dart:1
Warning: Mapping new ns ttp://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/02 to old ns ttp://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/01
Warning: Mapping new ns ttp://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/02 to old ns ttp://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/01
Warning: Mapping new ns ttp://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/02 to old ns ttp://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns ttp://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/03 to old ns ttp://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns ttp://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/02 to old ns ttp://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns ttp://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/03 to old ns ttp://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns ttp://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/03 to old ns ttp://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns ttp://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/02 to old ns ttp://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/01
Warning: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"base-extension"). Expected elements are <{}codename>,<{}layoutlib>,<{}api-level>

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'.

> Failed to query the value of task ':app:compileDebugKotlin' property 'compilerRunner$kotlin_gradle_plugin'.
> Kotlin could not find the required JDK tools in the Java installation. Make sure Kotlin compilation is running on a JDK, not JRE.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 27s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)

% flutter doctor -v

[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.10.5, on macOS 12.3.1 21E258 darwin-arm, locale
he-IL)
• Flutter version 2.10.5 at /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/flutter/2.10.5/flutter
• Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
• Framework revision 5464c5bac7 (13 days ago), 2022-04-18 09:55:37 -0700
• Engine revision 57d3bac3dd
• Dart version 2.16.2
• DevTools version 2.9.2

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version
32.1.0-rc1)
• Android SDK at /Users/alon/Library/Android/sdk
• Platform android-32, build-tools 32.1.0-rc1
• ANDROID_HOME = /Users/alon/Library/Android/sdk
• Java binary at: /Library/Internet
Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin/java
• Java version Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_331-b09)
• All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 13.3.1)
• Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
• CocoaPods version 1.11.3

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
• Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.1)
• Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
• Flutter plugin can be installed from:
 https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
• Dart plugin can be installed from:
 https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.11+0-b60-7772763)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.66.2)
• VS Code at /Users/alon/Desktop/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
• Flutter extension version 3.38.1

[✓] VS Code (version 1.66.2)
• VS Code at /Users/alon/Downloads/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
• Flutter extension version 3.38.1

[✓] Connected device (2 available)
• macOS (desktop) • macos  • darwin-arm64   • macOS 12.3.1 21E258 darwin-arm
• Chrome (web)    • chrome • web-javascript • Google Chrome 101.0.4951.41

[✓] HTTP Host Availability
• All required HTTP hosts are available

• No issues found!

help please :)

Comment: plz provide the `flutter doctor -v` output

Comment: hmmm, your output looks fine...

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63177661/flutter-error-kotlin-could-not-find-the-required-jdk-tools) may help

Comment: @iamdipanshus
its for windows pc and I'm using Mac :(

Comment: check the answers... most of them are irrespective of any platform