# Im facing flutter error while execution of app

Tags: flutter

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> Failed to find target with hash string 'android-28' in: C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Android\sdk

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 15m 16s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... Done                       927.4s (!)
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\flutter project\hello_world>

Comment: I think that there is some mistack in the android\settings.gradle file. Check the file against other projects or show ur your file.

Comment: That error says you've not downloaded Android SDK 28. What flutter guide are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Downgrade Java version to 8

If you don't want to use Java 8 for everything else on your system you can set the JDK to be used by gradle in **gradle.properties** [see](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21212790/2382389)

Comment: its not working i updated question please check i downloaded java 8 sdk

Comment: Just download the SDK for API 29 from Android SDK Manager or by launching Android standalone SDK manager.