# determining java version used in gradle build

Tags: java, gradle, javac

- Complementary to this question: [tell-gradle-to-use-specific-java-version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18487406/how-do-i-tell-gradle-to-use-specific-jdk-version)
- How can I determine (verify) the **java version actually used in gradle build**?
- After a successful `./gradlew build`, I looked for `javac`, but it was just in a binary file:

```
$ grep -rn "javac"
Binary file .gradle/4.6/taskHistory/taskHistory.bin matches
```

- I have many java versions installed, so a mixup is possible.
- Is there any way to verify the java version?

Answer (score 8):

`./gradlew --version` will tell you which jdk version you are using.

Comment: This gives the JRE version that gradle is running under. It could be different from the javac version it will use to compile java files.

Comment: This gives you the wrong java version.

Answer (score 3):

If you add `--info` to the build command it will tell you what java exe it is using for the compile:

`./gradlew build --info`

Then look for the string `Starting process` and you will see a line like:

```
Starting process 'Gradle Worker Daemon 10'. Working directory: C:\dev\.gradle\workers Command: C:\dev\.jdks\corretto-11.0.13\bin\java.exe ...'
```