# why does my flutter app not work after repeated reinstallations of java and gradle?

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin, dart, gradle

I have a problem with my Flutter app.
When I tried to start my app via an emulator, I got the following error message:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'.

> Kotlin could not find the required JDK tools in the Java installation 'C:\Program Files\AdoptOpenJDK\jre-11.0.11.9-hotspot' used by Gradle. Make sure Gradle is running on a JDK, not JRE.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
.

this is the standrad app which is created by flutter when creating a project and I have not changed it. When I received the message for the first time, I reinstalled gradle and java. but it didn't work. Can you help me?

Comment: So when you reinstalled, did you "Make sure Gradle is running on a JDK, not JRE."? If so, how?

Comment: no how do i do that? I have read it but read it re-istaliated it says nothing about jdk or jre

Comment: Well, what exactly did you install?

Comment: first of all I downloaded gardle (https://gradle.org/install/) and adjusted the PATH variable. then I never reinstalled java with the java installer

Comment: Well, what did the installer say, was it a JRE or JDK?

Comment: which installer? that of Java?

Comment: Yes, the Java installer.

Comment: it was the jdk installer

Comment: Then you will need to adjust the path gradle is using, right now its pointing at a JRE.

Comment: how do I do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I tell Gradle to use specific JDK version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18487406/how-do-i-tell-gradle-to-use-specific-jdk-version)

Comment: Yes of course. thanks