# Failed to apply plugin 'net.minecraftforge.gradle'. Found java version 16.0.1. Versions 16 and newer are not supported yet

Tags: java, gradle

Using Eclipse on Windows 10, I am trying to build the Minecraft Forge MDK, but Gradle tells me it can only find Java 16. Everything was working fine a week ago.

I don't have Java 16 installed except it's default installed for Eclipse.

My JAVA_HOME path is set to

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_291\bin .
```

Java 8 is installed and the build path on Eclipse is set to

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_291
```

Adding an *org.gradle.java.home* set to the same path as my JAVA_HOME returns an error saying there is no valid java home. I am unsure what to do.

Comment: Hello @BudgieGryphone, welcome to the Stackoverflow. Please check if this answers your question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18487406/how-do-i-tell-gradle-to-use-specific-jdk-version

Comment: Tried just about every option in that post and only received various errors, either the same one I started with, or when I tried the compileJava lines, gradle not being able to locate the compiler(despite me first trying to link to the bin containing the javac and then the javac itself.)