# Gradle build cannot find symbol for Path.of()

Tags: java, gradle

The project runs perfectly using Netbean's "build and run". However, due to the need to create a Fat Jar I had to add a gradle task CustomFatJar in build.gradle which looks like this:

```
    task customFatJar(type: Jar) {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'com.Reject.Main'
    }
    baseName = 'all-in-one-jar'
    from { configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
    with jar
}
```

Thus, running the gradle like this using command prompt:

```
gradle customFatJar
```

and then get this result :

```
 error: cannot find symbol
 try (InputStream is = Files.newInputStream(Path.of(""), StandardOpenOption.READ)) {
                                                       ^
 symbol:   method of(java.lang.String)
 location: interface java.nio.file.Path
```

I believe I have imported Java nio file path in the main class:

```
 import java.nio.file.Path;
```

I could not find any clue how to fix this as the code runs completely fine in the IDE.

Comment: can you post the block of code that causing error?

Comment: You are probably building with a JDK older than 11.

Comment: Can you please share the output of `java -version` when running from a terminal you use to build your project?

Comment: @dadan
try (InputStream is = Files.newInputStream(Path.of(path+dt_formatter.format(new Date())+".jrn"), StandardOpenOption.READ)) {
} catch {...}
finally{....}

its more of like that. I would like to edit my question instead of posting it here but  I couldn't find the button :(

Comment: @BjørnVester
java version "11.0.12" 2021-07-20 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.12+8-LTS-237)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.12+8-LTS-237, mixed mode)

Comment: @akortex
thats the java version

Comment: And is that the same version as when you run `gradle --version`? The reason we ask is that the `Path.of` method was first introduced in Java 11, so if you compile with a prior version you will get an error as you've shown.

Comment: @BjørnVester
totally missed that one, yes the gradle --version says java 1.8
and i follow this instruction :
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18487406/how-do-i-tell-gradle-to-use-specific-jdk-version)
`gradle build -Dorg.gradle.java.home=/JDK_PATH`
Many Thanks

Comment: You can also use the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable to set the path to the java distribution if that is easier for you.