# Gradle settings resetting every time Android Studio is opened

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, intellij-idea

Whenever I open my Flutter project's `android` module in Android Studio, it gives me the following error:

> Android Gradle plugin requires Java 11 to run. You are currently using Java 1.8.

To solve it, I open Gradle settings and change Gradle JDK from `1.8` to `11`, hit Apply button and it works.

[image]

However, if I reopen the same project (after closing), it resets my JDK to `1.8`. I need to set it to `11` again. What am I doing wrong?

**PS:** My other Android projects (native ones using Java) does remember the last selected JDK version.

Comment: Have you ever used IntelliJ IDEA with this project?

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21212790/2000323

Comment: @Andrey No, I didn't use IntelliJ IDEA for this project. Thanks for the link, I knew how to do that in gradle file but I'm curious to know why my Flutter project is having this issue.

Answer (score 0):

#### 2023 Update

I was trying to update from VERSION 1.8 to VERSION 11. Went through the solutions on the web and found none working. I couldn't find the file at the specified location. The file has been changed in the newer releases.

**Step 1:** Open the Android Studio and keep it open.

**Step 2:**
Go to the location given below:

```
C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudio2022.1\options
```

or press `Win + R` and enter the following:

```
%userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudio2022.1\options
```

Your latest version of Android Studio might be different.

**Step 3:** Delete the file `jdk.table.xml` from the options folder.

**Step 4:** Change the Gradle JDK to the new JDK in the settings, so that the Studio can save the new path in the file. (Important: Else Studio assigns JDK from it's memory)

**Step 5:** Restart Android Studio.

This fixed the issue for me. The newly created `jdk.table.xml` will have the updated JDK values.

Comment: Accept the answer if it helped you. Thanks in advance. I'm new to answering on StackOverflow.