# Can we force the use of a JDK as Gradle Java toolchain?

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle, build-system, gradle-java-toolchain

Gradle 6.7 introduced [*Java toolchains*](https://blog.gradle.org/java-toolchains).

In the documentation, they state that *Gradle chooses a JRE/JDK matching the requirements of the build ... By default, Gradle prefers installed JDKs over JREs...* (from [docs.gradle.org: Toolchains for JVM projects](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/toolchains.html)).

Thus, the JDK is chosen if we have both, JRE and JDK, installed.

**Problem:**

Imagine that the user only has a JRE installed.

Yet, we want to run our application via Gradle (`JavaExec` task) using a Java toolchain, but have to ensure that a JDK is used for running because this application relies on `tools.jar`, which is not part of a JRE.

**Question:**

Is it possible to force Gradle to use a JDK for all tasks (including running / launching), not just for compiling, when using a Java toolchain? (see following minimal example with comment)

```
// This build.gradle should ensure that the application is run using a JDK of version 9 
plugins {
    id 'application'
}
java {
    toolchain {
        languageVersion = JavaLanguageVersion.of(9)
        // QUESTION: How to force JDK here? <------
    }
}
// for JavaExec task runJar
tasks.withType(JavaExec).configureEach {
    javaLauncher = javaToolchains.launcherFor(java.toolchain)
}
task runJar(type: JavaExec) {
    classpath = files(jar.archiveFile)
}
...
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I tell Gradle to use specific JDK version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18487406/how-do-i-tell-gradle-to-use-specific-jdk-version)

Comment: @MartinZeitler: No, this does not answer my question. I do not care which Java version is used to run the _Gradle daemon_, neither do I want to manually set the JDK path to a certain location. I want to use Java toolchains for building AND running, and in both cases want to use a JDK, never a JRE. But thanks for the reference to the other question!

Comment: The JDK contains the JRE ...and Gradle will link against `rt.jar`, whether you like it or not. I'm pretty certain about it, because my Gradle plugin javadocs wouldn't build without it on classpath.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The **solution** I finally came up with:

I now use `org.gradle.java.installations.auto-detect=false` stored in a `settings.gradle` file in my project. This ignores any locally installed Java versions when using Java toolchains in Gradle.

Thus, it will download a suitable **JDK** on the first run, and will reuse this JDK on future runs.

*Upside*: We ensure that even if a local JRE exists, we download a JDK (e.g., we can be sure that `tools.jar` exists).

*Downside*: We also download a JDK if a matching one would exist on the machine.

Answer (score 2):

For those of us without internet on build machines per business requirement, *sigh*,
https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/toolchains.html
describes Selecting toolchains by vendor:

```
java {
    toolchain {
...
        vendor = JvmVendorSpec.ADOPTIUM // or vendor = JvmVendorSpec.matching("Private Build") in my case. find the Vendor = value you need with ./gradlew -q javaToolchains
    }
}
```

or even complete Custom toolchain locations:

`org.gradle.java.installations.fromEnv=JDK8,JRE17` //from env vars
`org.gradle.java.installations.paths=/custom/path/jdk1.8,/shared/jre11`

Answer (score 0):

What is the tool you are using? If it is IntelliJ, then

A feature in IntelliJ that where it would look up if java tool chain is configured and if it is, make it impossible for me to have mismatching configuration within:

Run configurations
Project Structure > Project SDK
Project Structure > Project Language Level

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LeSV4.png)

Comment: I run my Gradle scripts from the command line, not using any specific tools.

Answer (score -1):

One always has to add `rt.jar` first:

```
task runJar(type: JavaExec) {
    classpath = files(new File(System.getProperty('java.home') + File.separator + 'lib' + File.separator + 'rt.jar'))
    classpath += files(jar.archiveFile)
    ...
}
runJar.onlyIf {
    new File(System.getProperty('java.home') + File.separator + 'lib' + File.separator + 'rt.jar')).exists()
}
```

This probably would still require a `mainClassName` inside `jar.archiveFile`. With `JavaExec` one can set up whatever [`environment`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.JavaExec.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.JavaExec:environment) variable ...incl. `JAVA_HOME`, so this could be alternated per task. But one can as well use an `Exec` task on then directly run [`java`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/tools/java.html) `-jar some.jar`.
I wouldn't even be too certain, that these "runtime only" JRE distributions still exist?
All I know is that there is no `tools.jar`

Comment: "One always has to add rt.jar first" ... That is not true, why should I have to explicitly add rt.jar (which should be on the bootstrap path anyways? The `runJar` task stated in my question runs fine without a problem. And yes, there are "runtime-only" JREs, and this I need to ensure that the Java toolchain choses (and if necessary downloads) a JDK because we rely on JDI located in tools.jar. Sadly your answer does not include anything related to Java toolchain. (Side note: You are right that we have our jar configured to have a main class in its Manifest)

Comment: `java.toolchain` will download a JDK, when none is available; see `~/.gradle/jdks`. And I still haven't found any separate JRE package in my package manager... Oracle/Sun Java were distributed alike this. So it should be generally possible to globally force the use of `~/.gradle/jdks/xyz` (which is initially not there), but one can write `gradle.properties`, to pick up on second run; there's also `org.gradle.java.installations.auto-detect=false`. One even can specify it per task: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/toolchains.html#specify_custom_toolchains_for_individual_tasks

Comment: Plugin code provides some more flexibility (and Java might be easier to write than Groovy): https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/toolchains.html#sec:plugins

Comment: And in my example, the `classpath` is only being configured - and not given... which means I can link it to whatever version `rt.jar` I want to. Without the runtime `rt.jar`, nothing will link (despite this is rather related to Javadoc tasks).

Comment: eg. `org.gradle.java.installations.fromEnv=JDK8,JDK11` to only accept JDK installations.

Comment: This just needs `JDK8` and `JDK11` set up as environmental variables, with a path there... then these would be the preferred installations, whenever referring to them with `java.toolchain`.

Comment: "java.toolchain will download a JDK, when none is available" ... This is not true. It will _not_ download a JDK if a simple JRE is installed (e.g., only `openjdk-11-jre` is installed, but not `openjdk-11-jdk`) and no compile task is executed but a simple run task (such as `JavaExec`). Gradle would just use that openjdk-11-jre to run the program (it is important that I am talking about _running_ the already compiled program, not compiling it (which of course would need a JDK with a `javac`)).

Comment: **The solution:** I now use `org.gradle.java.installations.auto-detect=false`. This ignores any locally installed versions (both JRE or JDK), will download a *JDK* on first run, and will reuse that JDK on future runs. This ensures that a JDK is used also for `JavaExec` task.

Comment: Just found task `:javaToolchains`, which lists them all and also tells if it's JDK.