# gradlew genIntellijRuns failed, Could not resolve all files for configuration ':runtimeClasspathCopy'

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, minecraft-forge

I was trying to run my gradle project on Intellij IDEA but it gave me this error, this is the output when I ran it with `--stacktrace`:

```
To honour the JVM settings for this build a single-use Daemon process will be forked. See https://docs.gradle.org/7.3.3/userguide/gradle_daemon.html#sec:disabling_the_daemon.
Daemon will be stopped at the end of the build

> Configure project :
Java: 19.0.2 JVM: 19.0.2+7-44(Oracle Corporation) Arch: amd64
WARNING: This project is configured to use the official obfuscation mappings provided by Mojang. These mapping fall under their associated license, you should be fully aware of this license. For the latest license text, refer below, or the reference copy here: https://github.com/MinecraftForge/MCPConfig/blob/master/Mojang.md, You can hide this warning by running the `hideOfficialWarningUntilChanged` task
WARNING: (c) 2020 Microsoft Corporation. These mappings are provided "as-is" and you bear the risk of using them. You may copy and use the mappings for development purposes, but you may not redistribute the mappings complete and unmodified. Microsoft makes no warranties, express or implied, with respect to the mappings provided here.  Use and modification of this document or the source code (in any form) of Minecraft: Java Edition is governed by the Minecraft End User License Agreement available at https://account.mojang.com/documents/minecraft_eula.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find tools.jar. Please check that C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_361 contains a valid JDK installation.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.JdkTools.<init>(JdkTools.java:77)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.JavaHomeBasedJavaCompilerFactory.createJdkTools(JavaHomeBasedJavaCompilerFactory.java:48)
        at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(Unknown Source)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.JavaHomeBasedJavaCompilerFactory.create(JavaHomeBasedJavaCompilerFactory.java:43)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.JavaHomeBasedJavaCompilerFactory.create(JavaHomeBasedJavaCompilerFactory.java:29)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.JdkJavaCompiler.createCompileTask(JdkJavaCompiler.java:63)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.JdkJavaCompiler.execute(JdkJavaCompiler.java:53)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.JdkJavaCompiler.execute(JdkJavaCompiler.java:39)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.daemon.AbstractDaemonCompiler$CompilerWorkAction.execute(AbstractDaemonCompiler.java:135)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerServer.execute(DefaultWorkerServer.java:63)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractClassLoaderWorker$1.create(AbstractClassLoaderWorker.java:49)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractClassLoaderWorker$1.create(AbstractClassLoaderWorker.java:43)
        at org.gradle.internal.classloader.ClassLoaderUtils.executeInClassloader(ClassLoaderUtils.java:97)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractClassLoaderWorker.executeInClassLoader(AbstractClassLoaderWorker.java:43)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.FlatClassLoaderWorker.run(FlatClassLoaderWorker.java:32)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.FlatClassLoaderWorker.run(FlatClassLoaderWorker.java:22)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.WorkerDaemonServer.run(WorkerDaemonServer.java:85)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.WorkerDaemonServer.run(WorkerDaemonServer.java:55)
        at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.request.WorkerAction$1.call(WorkerAction.java:138)
        at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.WorkerLogEventListener.withWorkerLoggingProtocol(WorkerLogEventListener.java:41)
        at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.request.WorkerAction.run(WorkerAction.java:135)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
        at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
        at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:182)
        at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:164)
        at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:414)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find tools.jar. Please check that C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_361 contains a valid JDK installation.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.JdkTools.<init>(JdkTools.java:77)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.JavaHomeBasedJavaCompilerFactory.createJdkTools(JavaHomeBasedJavaCompilerFactory.java:48)
        at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(Unknown Source)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.JavaHomeBasedJavaCompilerFactory.create(JavaHomeBasedJavaCompilerFactory.java:43)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.JavaHomeBasedJavaCompilerFactory.create(JavaHomeBasedJavaCompilerFactory.java:29)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.JdkJavaCompiler.createCompileTask(JdkJavaCompiler.java:63)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.JdkJavaCompiler.execute(JdkJavaCompiler.java:53)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.JdkJavaCompiler.execute(JdkJavaCompiler.java:39)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.daemon.AbstractDaemonCompiler$CompilerWorkAction.execute(AbstractDaemonCompiler.java:135)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerServer.execute(DefaultWorkerServer.java:63)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractClassLoaderWorker$1.create(AbstractClassLoaderWorker.java:49)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractClassLoaderWorker$1.create(AbstractClassLoaderWorker.java:43)
        at org.gradle.internal.classloader.ClassLoaderUtils.executeInClassloader(ClassLoaderUtils.java:97)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractClassLoaderWorker.executeInClassLoader(AbstractClassLoaderWorker.java:43)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.FlatClassLoaderWorker.run(FlatClassLoaderWorker.java:32)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.FlatClassLoaderWorker.run(FlatClassLoaderWorker.java:22)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.WorkerDaemonServer.run(WorkerDaemonServer.java:85)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.WorkerDaemonServer.run(WorkerDaemonServer.java:55)
        at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.request.WorkerAction$1.call(WorkerAction.java:138)
        at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.WorkerLogEventListener.withWorkerLoggingProtocol(WorkerLogEventListener.java:41)
        at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.request.WorkerAction.run(WorkerAction.java:135)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
        at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
        at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:182)
        at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:164)
        at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:414)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not resolve all files for configuration ':runtimeClasspathCopy'.
> Could not find net.minecraftforge:forge:1.16.5-36.2.34_mapped_official_1.16.5.
  Searched in the following locations:
    - file:/C:/Users/Charles Pitcher/.gradle/caches/forge_gradle/bundeled_repo/net/minecraftforge/forge/1.16.5-36.2.34_mapped_official_1.16.5/forge-1.16.5-36.2.34_mapped_official_1.16.5.pom
    - file:/C:/Users/Charles Pitcher/.gradle/caches/forge_gradle/bundeled_repo/net/minecraftforge/forge/1.16.5-36.2.34_mapped_official_1.16.5/forge-1.16.5-36.2.34_mapped_official_1.16.5.jar
  Required by:
      project :

* Try:
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':runtimeClasspathCopy'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.rethrowFailure(DefaultConfiguration.java:1423)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.access$3600(DefaultConfiguration.java:152)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$DefaultResolutionHost.rethrowFailure(DefaultConfiguration.java:2035)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$ConfigurationFileCollection.visitContents(DefaultConfiguration.java:1395)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.visitContents(DefaultConfiguration.java:498)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.AbstractFileCollection.getFiles(AbstractFileCollection.java:130)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration_Decorated.getFiles(Unknown Source)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.resolve(DefaultConfiguration.java:488)
        at net.minecraftforge.gradle.common.util.runs.RunConfigGenerator.getResolvedClasspath(RunConfigGenerator.java:233)
        at net.minecraftforge.gradle.common.util.runs.RunConfigGenerator.createRuntimeClassPathList(RunConfigGenerator.java:241)
        at net.minecraftforge.gradle.common.util.runs.RunConfigGenerator.configureTokensLazy(RunConfigGenerator.java:199)
        at net.minecraftforge.gradle.common.util.runs.RunConfigGenerator.createRunTask(RunConfigGenerator.java:256)
        at net.minecraftforge.gradle.common.util.runs.RunConfigGenerator.createRunTask(RunConfigGenerator.java:229)
        at net.minecraftforge.gradle.common.util.Utils.lambda$null$10(Utils.java:409)
        at net.minecraftforge.gradle.common.util.Utils.lambda$createRunConfigTasks$11(Utils.java:409)
        at org.gradle.configuration.internal.DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext$CurrentApplication$1.execute(DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext.java:123)
        at org.gradle.configuration.internal.DefaultListenerBuildOperationDecorator$BuildOperationEmittingAction$1.run(DefaultListenerBuildOperationDecorator.java:152)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:47)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:68)
        at org.gradle.configuration.internal.DefaultListenerBuildOperationDecorator$BuildOperationEmittingAction.execute(DefaultListenerBuildOperationDecorator.java:149)
        at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$ActionInvocationHandler.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:95)
        at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$ActionInvocationHandler.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:83)
        at org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:43)
        at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$SingletonDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:245)
        at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$SingletonDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:157)
        at org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:61)
        at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$CompositeDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:346)
        at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$CompositeDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:249)
        at org.gradle.internal.event.ListenerBroadcast.dispatch(ListenerBroadcast.java:141)
        at org.gradle.internal.event.ListenerBroadcast.dispatch(ListenerBroadcast.java:37)
        at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:94)
        at jdk.proxy1/jdk.proxy1.$Proxy27.projectsEvaluated(Unknown Source)
        at org.gradle.initialization.ProjectsEvaluatedNotifier$NotifyProjectsEvaluatedListeners.run(ProjectsEvaluatedNotifier.java:47)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:47)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:68)
        at org.gradle.initialization.ProjectsEvaluatedNotifier.notify(ProjectsEvaluatedNotifier.java:35)
        at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultProjectsPreparer.prepareProjects(DefaultProjectsPreparer.java:49)
        at org.gradle.configuration.BuildTreePreparingProjectsPreparer.prepareProjects(BuildTreePreparingProjectsPreparer.java:64)
        at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationFiringProjectsPreparer$ConfigureBuild.run(BuildOperationFiringProjectsPreparer.java:52)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:47)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:68)
        at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationFiringProjectsPreparer.prepareProjects(BuildOperationFiringProjectsPreparer.java:40)
        at org.gradle.initialization.VintageBuildModelController.lambda$prepareProjects$1(VintageBuildModelController.java:93)
        at org.gradle.internal.build.StateTransitionController.lambda$doTransition$1(StateTransitionController.java:222)
        at org.gradle.internal.build.StateTransitionController.doTransition(StateTransitionController.java:243)
        at org.gradle.internal.build.StateTransitionController.doTransition(StateTransitionController.java:221)
        at org.gradle.internal.build.StateTransitionController.transitionIfNotPreviously(StateTransitionController.java:190)
        at org.gradle.initialization.VintageBuildModelController.prepareProjects(VintageBuildModelController.java:93)
        at org.gradle.initialization.VintageBuildModelController.doBuildStages(VintageBuildModelController.java:77)
        at org.gradle.initialization.VintageBuildModelController.prepareToScheduleTasks(VintageBuildModelController.java:64)
        at org.gradle.internal.build.DefaultBuildLifecycleController.lambda$prepareToScheduleTasks$0(DefaultBuildLifecycleController.java:105)
        at org.gradle.internal.build.StateTransitionController.lambda$doTransition$1(StateTransitionController.java:222)
        at org.gradle.internal.build.StateTransitionController.doTransition(StateTransitionController.java:243)
        at org.gradle.internal.build.StateTransitionController.doTransition(StateTransitionController.java:221)
        at org.gradle.internal.build.StateTransitionController.maybeTransition(StateTransitionController.java:174)
        at org.gradle.internal.build.DefaultBuildLifecycleController.prepareToScheduleTasks(DefaultBuildLifecycleController.java:103)
        at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeWorkPreparer.scheduleRequestedTasks(DefaultBuildTreeWorkPreparer.java:33)
        at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.lambda$doScheduleAndRunTasks$2(DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.java:86)
        at org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultIncludedBuildTaskGraph.withNewTaskGraph(DefaultIncludedBuildTaskGraph.java:94)
        at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.doScheduleAndRunTasks(DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.java:85)
        at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.lambda$runBuild$4(DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.java:103)
        at org.gradle.internal.build.StateTransitionController.lambda$transition$0(StateTransitionController.java:145)
        at org.gradle.internal.build.StateTransitionController.doTransition(StateTransitionController.java:243)
        at org.gradle.internal.build.StateTransitionController.transition(StateTransitionController.java:145)
        at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.runBuild(DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.java:100)
        at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.scheduleAndRunTasks(DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.java:66)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(ExecuteBuildActionRunner.java:31)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
        at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.ProblemReportingBuildActionRunner.run(ProblemReportingBuildActionRunner.java:49)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildOutcomeReportingBuildActionRunner.run(BuildOutcomeReportingBuildActionRunner.java:69)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.FileSystemWatchingBuildActionRunner.run(FileSystemWatchingBuildActionRunner.java:114)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildCompletionNotifyingBuildActionRunner.run(BuildCompletionNotifyingBuildActionRunner.java:41)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RootBuildLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.lambda$execute$0(RootBuildLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.java:40)
        at org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultRootBuildState.run(DefaultRootBuildState.java:155)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RootBuildLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.execute(RootBuildLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.java:40)
        at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeContext.execute(DefaultBuildTreeContext.java:40)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.lambda$execute$0(BuildTreeLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.java:65)
        at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.BuildTreeState.run(BuildTreeState.java:53)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.execute(BuildTreeLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.java:65)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor$3.call(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor.java:61)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor$3.call(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor.java:57)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor.execute(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor.java:57)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsWorkerThreadBuildActionExecutor.lambda$execute$0(RunAsWorkerThreadBuildActionExecutor.java:38)
        at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:211)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsWorkerThreadBuildActionExecutor.execute(RunAsWorkerThreadBuildActionExecutor.java:38)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecutor.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecutor.java:103)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionExecutor.execute(SubscribableBuildActionExecutor.java:64)
        at org.gradle.internal.session.DefaultBuildSessionContext.execute(DefaultBuildSessionContext.java:46)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter$ActionImpl.apply(BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:100)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter$ActionImpl.apply(BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:88)
        at org.gradle.internal.session.BuildSessionState.run(BuildSessionState.java:69)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:62)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:41)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:25)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:63)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:31)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:58)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:42)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:47)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:31)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:65)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:39)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:29)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.create(ForwardClientInput.java:78)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.create(ForwardClientInput.java:75)
        at org.gradle.util.internal.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:75)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:50)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:63)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:84)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:52)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:297)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:61)
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionNotFoundException: Could not find net.minecraftforge:forge:1.16.5-36.2.34_mapped_official_1.16.5.
Searched in the following locations:
  - file:/C:/Users/Charles Pitcher/.gradle/caches/forge_gradle/bundeled_repo/net/minecraftforge/forge/1.16.5-36.2.34_mapped_official_1.16.5/forge-1.16.5-36.2.34_mapped_official_1.16.5.pom
  - file:/C:/Users/Charles Pitcher/.gradle/caches/forge_gradle/bundeled_repo/net/minecraftforge/forge/1.16.5-36.2.34_mapped_official_1.16.5/forge-1.16.5-36.2.34_mapped_official_1.16.5.jar
Required by:
    project :


* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/7.3.3/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 1m
```

I don't know what to do as I am quite new to Java and IntelliJ.

Comment: Can you please show your `build.gradle` or `build.gradle.kts`? Also, do you have a JDK installed? Is your `JAVA_HOME` set to that JDK? What's the output of `java -version` and `javac -version`?

Comment: It looks like your JAVA_HOME environment variable is pointing to a JRE and not a JDK. You need install JDK package and set it as new JAVA_HOME.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18487406/how-do-i-tell-gradle-to-use-specific-jdk-version

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I tell Gradle to use specific JDK version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18487406/how-do-i-tell-gradle-to-use-specific-jdk-version)