# Can't build created by start.spring.io, Unsupported class file major version 61

Tags: spring-boot, gradle

My environment is Neon Linux

```
└─$ java --version
java 19.0.2 2023-01-17
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 19.0.2+7-44)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 19.0.2+7-44, mixed mode, sharing)
┌──(katya5㉿computer)-[/home/katya/personal/my_site_stub/site]
└─$ javac --version
javac 19.0.2
```

I have created the following spring boot project https://ibb.co/VMRwx48
And trying to build it with command

```
─$ gradle --stacktrace

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'site'.
> Failed to create Jar file /home/katya5/.gradle/caches/jars-8/b1e32c3edc578ad1464e1722f1fcd639/spring-boot-gradle-plugin-3.0.6.jar.

...
...

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 61
        at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:196)
        at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:177)
        at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:163)
        at org.gradle.internal.classpath.InstrumentingClasspathFileTransformer.lambda$visitEntries$1(InstrumentingClasspathFileTransformer.java:116)
        at org.gradle.internal.classpath.ClasspathWalker.visitJarContents(ClasspathWalker.java:91)
        at org.gradle.internal.classpath.ClasspathWalker.visit(ClasspathWalker.java:55)
        at org.gradle.internal.classpath.InstrumentingClasspathFileTransformer.visitEntries(InstrumentingClasspathFileTransformer.java:114)
        at org.gradle.internal.classpath.InstrumentingClasspathFileTransformer.lambda$instrument$0(InstrumentingClasspathFileTransformer.java:105)
        at org.gradle.internal.classpath.ClasspathBuilder.buildJar(ClasspathBuilder.java:58)
        at org.gradle.internal.classpath.ClasspathBuilder.jar(ClasspathBuilder.java:45)
        ... 7 more


* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

full log is here https://gist.github.com/nikhil-j-oshi/1f0c637cdfc18a05f0b6a33fe83d3d94
`
**UPD:** problem soved by updating to to Gradle 8.1.1!

Why it fails? I have propper JAVA environment (version 19!!) what is wrong?

gradle --stacktrace
I expected proper build of JAR

**UPD: problem was solved by upgradingto Gradle 8.1.1!**

Comment: `java --version` uses the "first (found) java in your $PATH", gradle prefers $JAVA_HOME (before falling back to $PATH)

Comment: relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18487406/how-do-i-tell-gradle-to-use-specific-jdk-version

Comment: @xerx593 I believe that it is not a problem, please take a look at my environment https://gist.github.com/nikhil-j-oshi/233b93007d3c91af04679b34ff183aa3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem was solved by upgrading to Gradle 8.1.1!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).