# How to set gradle wrapper default JDK location

Tags: java, android, gradlew

Every time I am using gradlew (gradle-wrapper), I have to pass the path of my JDK to make it work like this:

```
./gradlew lint -Dorg.gradle.java.home=/Users/kevinabrioux/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/corretto-18.0.2/Contents/Home
```

When I am executing without setting JDK, I have this error:

[image]

How to configure my gradlew to make it work without `-Dorg.gradle.java.home` argument ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/18487406/150978

Comment: @Robert I have no issue with gradle, only gradle-wrapper have issue with my JDK version.

Everything compile fine when using only gradle. I don't think there is the same issue.

Comment: But gradle-wrapper is just a wrapper around gradle. The only difference is that if you execute gradle directly the version your system has installed is used where as when you use gradlew a fixed gradle version is used. So in the end in both ways you execute gradle. Ans the error message clearly shows that it is caused by gradle not the wraper running before. BTW: Why a screenshot? You should know SO well enough to not make those beginner's mistakes...

Comment: @Robert You are right, sorry for this mistake

Comment: @Robert It was in fact a duplicate from the answer you have linked. The first answer was the right one. I don't know why one month ago I was enable to fix it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the default Java version installed on your Mac (and used by the terminal) is different from the one expected to build the project (Java 18).

I'm expecting that if you set your `JAVA_HOME` env variable to

```
/Users/kevinabrioux/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/corretto-18.0.2/Contents/Home
```

then gradlew won't complain and the `-Dorg.gradle.java.home` won't be needed.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I have found the issue:

I needed to set the java home in the global `.gradle/gradle.properties` file

with

```
org.gradle.java.home=/Users/kevinabrioux/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/corretto-18.0.2/Contents/Home
```