Issue in upgradation from spring 2.x to spring 3.2.0
Hi I have added plugins and dependencies as given in the following link to my project : https://docs.openrewrite.org/recipes/java/spring/boot3/upgradespringboot_3_2
but after running and changes have been applied, I am getting following error when trying to run the service:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'FormService'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:3.2.5.
     Required by:
         project : > org.springframework.boot:org.springframework.boot.gradle.plugin:3.2.5
      > No matching variant of org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:3.2.5 was found. The consumer was configured to find a runtime of a library compatible with Java 11, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally, as well as attribute 'org.gradle.plugin.api-version' with value '7.6.4' but:
          - Variant 'apiElements' capability org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:3.2.5 declares a library, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares an API of a component compatible with Java 17 and the consumer needed a runtime of a component compatible with Java 11
              - Other compatible attribute:
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '7.6.4')
          - Variant 'javadocElements' capability org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:3.2.5 declares a runtime of a component, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares documentation and the consumer needed a library
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 11)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '7.6.4')
          - Variant 'mavenOptionalApiElements' capability org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin-maven-optional:3.2.5 declares a library, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares an API of a component compatible with Java 17 and the consumer needed a runtime of a component compatible with Java 11
              - Other compatible attribute:
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '7.6.4')
          - Variant 'mavenOptionalRuntimeElements' capability org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin-maven-optional:3.2.5 declares a runtime of a library, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component compatible with Java 17 and the consumer needed a component compatible with Java 11
              - Other compatible attribute:
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '7.6.4')
          - Variant 'runtimeElements' capability org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:3.2.5 declares a runtime of a library, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component compatible with Java 17 and the consumer needed a component compatible with Java 11
              - Other compatible attribute:
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '7.6.4')
          - Variant 'sourcesElements' capability org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:3.2.5 declares a runtime of a component, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares documentation and the consumer needed a library
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 11)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '7.6.4')

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 282ms

Open Rewrite/ Spring Boot

Spring boot 3.x requires java 17 https://spring.io/blog/2022/05/24/preparing-for-spring-boot-3-0. You have to make sure gradle uses java 17 as well.

I have configured the project structure to JDK 17 as well. But the issue still persists. Can you specifically tell me how to achieve what you are telling me to?

are you using idea intellij? if not this might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18487406/how-do-i-tell-gradle-to-use-specific-jdk-version

Yes I am using intelliJ idea

in idea, go to settings and search for gradle. there you can change the gradle jvm
